# Should aliases go in .bashrc or .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, shell, environment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

It seems that if I use

```
alias ls='ls -F'
```

inside of .bashrc on Mac OS X, then the newly created shell will not have that alias. I need to type `bash` again and that alias will be in effect.

And if I log into Linux on the hosting company, the `.bashrc` file has a comment line that says:

> For non-login shell

and the `.bash_profile` file has a comment that says

> for login shell

So where should aliases be written in? How come we separate the login shell and non-login shell?

Some webpage say use `.bash_aliases`, but it doesn't work on Mac OS X, it seems.

Comment: Oh, this is dumb.  This question has been around for almost two years.  it's NOT an exact duplicate, since this one asks for prescriptive suggestions (what should be done).

Comment: aliases should go in the dust bin of history.  Use functions.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The reason you separate the *login* and *non-login* shell is because the `.bashrc` file is reloaded every time you start a new copy of Bash. The `.profile` file is loaded only when you either log in or use the appropriate flag to tell Bash to act as a login shell.

Personally,

- I put my `PATH` setup into a `.profile` file (because I sometimes use other shells);
- I put my Bash aliases and functions into my `.bashrc` file;
- I put this

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  #
  # CRM .bash_profile Time-stamp: "2008-12-07 19:42"
  #
  # echo "Loading ${HOME}/.bash_profile"
  source ~/.profile # get my PATH setup
  source ~/.bashrc  # get my Bash aliases
  ```

  in my `.bash_profile` file.

Oh, and the reason you need to type `bash` again to get the new alias is that Bash loads your `.bashrc` file when it starts but it doesn't reload it unless you tell it to. You can reload the `.bashrc` file (and not need a second shell) by typing

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

which loads the `.bashrc` file as if you had typed the commands directly to Bash.

Comment: It is supposed to be the other way round: `.bash_profile` sources `.bashrc`, and you use a non-login shell after logging in the first time.

Comment: Go read what I said again.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Just wonder what it means exactly "bash loads your .bashrc when it starts". Do you mean when the machine starts or when the terminal start?

Comment: whenever a bash process starts.  Say I do:

    $ bash
    $ bash
    $ bash

then I have four `bash` processes running. .bashrc is loaded by each process.

Comment: That's just three calls to bash, so wouldn't that just make three bash processes? And doesn't one bash process have to terminate before the next one starts, or do they run in parallel for some reason?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye there's one bash process executing that command lines: to start. Think of it as bash_0, then it starts bash_1, which starts bash_2, which starts bash_3, for a total of 4.

Comment: Ah, that's true. But still, by `$ bash $ bash $ bash`, do you mean that you run the bash command in three separate commands, so one has to terminate before the next one starts and they don't run in parallel? Or is that maybe unimportant for this example?

Comment: There should have been newlines between them but comments wouldn't do that. There are four shells running concurrently (not in parallel, strictly) but three of them are suspended waiting for a child to terminate.  Now, for a good time, try `$ bash & bash & bash &`.

Comment: @CharlieMartin nice answer, I'm gonna reference this on my blog.  Bookmarked as well.

Comment: @CharlieMartin this is ancient and if you are still using this method maybe you could explain what the commented-out lines do and why they are commented out? Should/could these be removed for someone who is following your example? Thanks!

Comment: @CharlieMartin I would also like to point out that if you open another shell and use `login` to login as a different user - having the commands  `source ~/.profile` and `source ~/.bashrc` will not source from the newly logged in user's home folder but the home folder of the user you signed into your computer with. Maybe there is another solution than using `~/`

Comment: @John The top comment is a "shebang" line, which tells exec what interpreter the file uses. It's only needed if you set the x bit on the file and run it directly. You almost never do that with .profile but it's a habit.  The line starting with CRM is just a time stamp — from the format I suspect it's an SVN time stamp but it's been a long time. And you're right, if you log in as someone else it's going to source *their* .profile etc and not yours. If you just want to change the UID, us su or sudo.

Answer (score 145):

Check out http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles for an excellent resource on the topic aside from `man bash`.

Summary:

- You only log in once, and that's when `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` is read and executed.  Since everything you run from your login shell inherits the login shell's environment, you should put all your **environment variables** in there.  Like `LESS`, `PATH`, `MANPATH`, `LC_*`, ... For an example, see: [My `.profile`](http://stuff.lhunath.com/.profile)
- Once you log in, you can run several more shells.  Imagine logging in, running X, and in X starting a few terminals with bash shells.  That means your login shell started X, which inherited your login shell's environment variables, which started your terminals, which started your non-login bash shells.  Your environment variables were passed along in the whole chain, so your non-login shells don't need to load them anymore.  Non-login shells only execute `~/.bashrc`, not `/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, for this exact reason, so in there define everything that **only applies to bash**.  That's functions, aliases, **bash-only variables like HISTSIZE (this is not an environment variable, don't export it!)**, shell options with `set` and `shopt`, etc. For an example, see: [My `.bashrc`](http://stuff.lhunath.com/.bashrc)
- Now, as part of UNIX peculiarity, a login-shell does NOT execute `~/.bashrc` but only `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, so you should source that one manually from the latter.  You'll see me do that in my `~/.profile` too: `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: This answer deserves way more upvotes. Right now I came back looking things up for the fourth time.

Comment: Also see: https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html

Comment: Following 2 URLS -Cleared my Years of Confusion                                 
https://linuxize.com/post/bashrc-vs-bash-profile/                   
https://medium.com/@abhinavkorpal/bash-profile-vs-bashrc-c52534a787d3

Answer (score 13):

From the bash manpage:

> When  bash is invoked as an
>   interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the
>   `--login` option, it first reads and executes  commands  from  the file
>   `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. 
>   After reading that file, it looks for
>   `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and
>   `~/.profile`, in  that order, and reads
>   and executes commands from the first
>   one that exists and is readable.  The
>   `--noprofile` option may be  used  when  the shell is started to inhibit this
>   behavior.
>
> When  a login  shell  exits, bash
>   reads and executes commands from the
>   file `~/.bash_logout`, if it exists.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash
>          reads  and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.  This
>          may be inhibited by using the `--norc` option.  The `--rcfile` file  option
>          will  force  bash  to  read  and  execute commands from file instead of
>          `~/.bashrc`.

Thus, if you want to get the same behavior for both login shells and interactive non-login shells, you should put all of your commands in either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, and then have the other file [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-source-144) the first one.

Answer (score 4):

`.bash_profile` is loaded for a "login shell". I am not sure what that would be on OS X, but on Linux that is either X11 or a virtual terminal.

`.bashrc` is loaded every time you run Bash. That is where you should put stuff you want loaded whenever you open a new Terminal.app window.

I personally put everything in `.bashrc` so that I don't have to restart the application for changes to take effect.