# Put current git branch to project version

Tags: git, maven, versioning

I want to put the current git branch into the version field in pom xml. I found some post in the internet suggesting to do something like:

```
<version>${scm.version}</version>
```

but this seems not to work with git. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deriving maven artifact version from git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583953/deriving-maven-artifact-version-from-git-branch)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, use the [git commit id plugin for maven](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin)

It's pretty straightforward. You can use it to get the git branch with

```
${git.branch}
```

So in your case it would go:

```
<version>${git.branch}</version>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work in a multi module maven project because the reactors executes before any plugin is executed and it needs the version to be set to a constant or it fails

Comment: Works Great! Thanks

Comment: this is actually not supported, here is a workaround but not suggested https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/issues/256#issuecomment-321476196

Answer (score 0):

i created a plugin for this behavior (and by extend to link sonar to my maven projects).

The only thing you need to do is

add following plugin to your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.viae-it.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>LATEST</version>
</plugin>
```

call the plugin to set the git branch

```
mvn com.viae-it.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:set-git-branch
```

then you can use the sonar.branch property