# How to get current Git branch name in Eclipse run configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, automated-tests

I am running Eclipse with Maven, eGit and TestNG plugins, with my tests running against SauceLabs.

I would like to get the project's current Git branch name in the Maven run configuration so my code can see it at runtime and name the SauceLabs session appropriately.

A typical current Maven goals line in a run configuration looks like this:

```
-DtestNG.suiteXmlFile="config/regress_saucelabs.xml" clean -X test
```

I would like to be able to write something like the following instead:

```
-DtestNG.suiteXmlFile="config/regress_saucelabs.xml" -Dgit.branch=$ECLIPSE_GIT_BRANCH clean -X test
```

where ECLIPSE_GIT_BRANCH is an Eclipse variable that gets substituted when the run configuration is used.

Runtime solutions are a last resort, because the test code needs to also run in environments where the source repository is not available.

Strongly prefer injecting the branch name at build time, on the Maven command line. Getting it as a POM variable would work well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never use it but it looks like JGit is what you are looking for (https://doc.nuxeo.com/blog/jgit-example/)

Another solution is to call the shell command `git branch` in Java and then parse the result.

Another solution using maven plugin is explained here : [Put current git branch to project version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553304/put-current-git-branch-to-project-version)

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this if I can't get anything that solves the problem at build time.

Comment: @DanHankins I updated my answer with another solution, if you really don't want to do it in Java code

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but doesn't work from an Eclipse Maven run configuration. The shell's not available from there.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553304/put-current-git-branch-to-project-version

Comment: The maven git-commit-id-plugin plugin did the trick. Winner winner chicken dinner. Thanks!