# git merge: keep one file intact but rest of the commit merged

Tags: git, maven

I have a maven project which have 2 git branches (master and develop), each branch have different maven artifact Id in the **pom.xml**.

So when i branch out and merge back between master and develop how do i make sure 2 branches have their own pom.xml unchanged. only the rest of the changes are moved around?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it, it is bad practice. The file should be same. If you need a difference, you could use a maven plugin which could read current branch name (e.g. `buildnumber-maven-plugin` gives `${scmBranch}`) and change maven properties such as artifact ID accordingly.

Also it is bad idea to change artifact ID depending on branch. Better to change a version prefix.

Comment: but i am not very sure about the 'version prefix'.  can you give an example?

Comment: @hotspring Apparently you could do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583953/deriving-maven-artifact-version-from-git-branch
But I prefer to have something like CI server (e.g. Jenkins) which does all the magic.