# Setting an env variable from post-checkout hook in git

Tags: git, shell, environment-variables

I've got a work environment in which I frequently build binaries and then kick off long-running processes using that binary. While these are running, I would like to switch to another git branch and do some work there, and potentially build some new binaries that wouldn't overwrite the ones currently running.

Right now, the build and run scripts use a `$OUT_DIR` env variable to determine the output dir for binaries. Ideally, I would like to have `$OUT_DIR` be branch-specific to avoid the above mentioned problem of builds overwriting each other.
At first, this seemed like a simple job for the post-checkout hook -- set `OUT_DIR` to be `OUT_DIR_BASE + "/" + current branch`... except post-checkout hook runs in a child shell so it can't set parent env variables.

Are there any clever ways to get around this?

Some ideas I've considered:

- I could output the "`export OUT_DIR...`" command to a file and make the
  user source it -- that's annoying and people will forget to do it.
- I could write the new `OUT_DIR` into an .rc file and have build/run scripts
  pick it up from there, but that requires changes to the build
  environment, and user experience gets a bit worse (i.e. you can't do "`cd $OUT_DIR`" to get into the output directory...
- I could write a wrapper for '`git checkout`' that would open a
  new shell with `OUT_DIR` set appropriately... but that's "leaking"
  shells where over time I'd have quite a large number running.

None of these seem very nice for what feels like should be an easy solution.

Answer (score 3):

> I could print the branch name into a file and have build/run scripts pick it up from there

That remains the way to explore, even though it involve modifying the build script.

But [getting the current branch name for a repo isn't hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142066/6309):

```
git -C /path/to/repo rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

So you wouldn't need to write the name of the current branch: the build script could get it directly from the repo.

Comment: Thanks! I should've elaborated on that point a bit more -- it wasn't so much that getting the branch name is hard, I was thinking more of writing out the OUT_DIR to an .rc file or some sorts, therefore keeping the scripts/build still decoupled from git.

Comment: @Stan I understand. I just thought if the script has access to those git repos anyway, this was easier.

Comment: @Stan Thanks for posting this question. I am trying to do the exact same thing and facing same sub-shell issue. Just curious, were you able to find any solution?