# Merge upstream without specifying branch name

Tags: git

I'm using Git with many feature branches.

When I want to update `master` and `featureX`

```sh
# Update master
git checkout master
git pull

# Update featureX
git checkout featureX
git pull
```

It works and simply. But it takes a while because I run `git pull` including `fetch` twice.

In another way...

```
# Update featureX
git checkout featureX
git merge origin/featureX
```

OK, I fetched only once. But I have to specify `origin/featureX` even the branch is upstream.

Is there an alias for upstream, or easy way to update branch without fetching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10014163/2896874), an alias for upstream is

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref @{u}
```

Comment: In this case, I don't need `rev-parse` because `@{u}` is also valid. So `git merge @{u}` works fine! Thanks!