# TFS 2012 GetBranch Name during build

Tags: branch, tfsbuild

There is an environment variable in TFS 2013 for Branch name.  However my company still uses TFS 2012.

Does anyone know how I can get the branch name during build with TFS 2012?

Is there a class with the branch name property in the TFS Build api?

I haven't found one yet.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can access the paths that are configured for this build through the **IBuildDetails**.

> Just use the **VersionControlServer** class to query the
>   BranchObjects, then check which one is the root for your working
>   folder.

*Sample Code:*

```
IBuildDetail buildDetail = context.GetExtension<IBuildDetail>();

 var workspace = buildDetail.BuildDefinition.Workspace;
 var versionControlServer = buildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

 var branches = versionControlServer.QueryRootBranchObjects(RecursionType.Full);
 var referencedBranches = listOfFilePaths.GroupBy(
                file =>
                branches.SingleOrDefault(
                     branch => file.ServerItem.StartsWith(branch.Properties.RootItem.Item)
                )
            ).Where(group => group.Key != null);
```

More details please refer *jessehouwing's* reply in this question: [Include branch name in post build event on Team Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828923/include-branch-name-in-post-build-event-on-team-build)