# Git shell command alias giving a "bad config file" error

Tags: git, bash, shell

I'm working on the following git alias

```
[alias]
  pushup = !git push --set-upstream origin `git branch | egrep "^\*" | awk -F"*" '{print $NF}'`
```

which is supposed to do a git push while simultaneously setting the upstream to the current branch.

The command

```
git push --set-upstream origin `git branch | egrep "^\*" | awk -F"*" '{print $NF}'`
```

works fine by itself on the command-line but I get a *bad config file* error when I try to use it as a git alias.

Clearly I don't understand something about the format of git aliases. Anyone want to enlighten me?

Comment: Wild guess, but what's up with that `!`? Shouldn't `!git` be `git`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. used to run external commands in git aliases. (Needed for the command substitution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong, but the following simplified alias works for me:

```
[alias]
    pushup = !git push --set-upstream origin $(git branch | awk '/^*/{print $2}')
```

Instead of grepping for `*` and then splitting on it, you could rely on `awk`'s splitting on whitespace to automatically get you the branch name as the second field, and use `awk` do `grep`'s job as well.

Vim highlights `\*` as an error, and when I try with it, I get the error you got (I'm using `echo` for debugging :D):

[image]

So that's the cause of the error. I still don't know *why*.

I suppose you could also use the simpler command from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142066/2072269):

```
[alias]
    pushup = !git push --set-upstream origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for A.) telling about using awk to do the grep part, and B.) a much tidier way to get the name of the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that `\` is recognized as an escaping character while parsing the alias. The parser expects something that needs escaping after the `\`, but the asterisk doesn't fit the bill.

You should escape the `\` with a second backslash to make the parser happy and pass it along to `egrep`. Like this:

```
[alias]
  pushup = !git push --set-upstream origin `git branch | egrep "^\\*" | awk -F"*" '{print $NF}'`
```