# Git: Easiest way to get the branch to which HEAD points

Tags: git

I need a git command that returns the name of the branch to which `HEAD` points. I.e., when I am on `master`, it should return `master`. In detached HEAD state, it can return either nothing or something that I will not confuse with a branch name. What is the easiest command to achieve this?

(Sorry, the question seems to be rather trivial and was probably asked a gazillion of times, but searching for things like "get branch to which HEAD points" didn't give me a satisfying result.)

Comment: You could just read .git/HEAD

Comment: `git symbolic-ref HEAD`

Comment: @MrTux: Thanks :). Feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: `git branch --points-at HEAD`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current branch name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probaply looking for:

- `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`
- `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

But it's also possible to manually read `.git/HEAD`

Comment: These are the two best ways to do this from a script. There is an important difference between them: the `git symbolic-ref` command fails (with an error message) if your HEAD is "detached", while the `git rev-parse --abbrev-rev` command prints `HEAD` for this case. So if you want `HEAD` printed for this case, use `git rev-parse`; if you want to check, and use a different code path for detached HEAD, use `git symbolic-ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to add an alias to git config.

```
git config --global alias.current "!git branch|grep '*'"

git current # should return the name of current branch.
```

Note: You can use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` too instead of `grep` to find the current branch as @MrTux suggested.