# Capture current branch name and delete it using Git alias on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, git-alias

Currently I'm using this alias to fetch master in the background and then switch to it. This way Visual Studio works the fastest for me:

```
[alias]
  fetch-checkout = !git fetch -p && git fetch origin master:master && git checkout master
```

What I'd like to do on top of that is to capture current branch name and delete it afterwards.

Is it possible on Windows?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean with *capture*? Is printing the name of the branch enough?

Comment: @alfunx: save into a variable, e.g. `%branch%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't delete a branch you're currently on, you would need to use some kind of temporary storage for the old branch's name. Something like:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD > tmp.txt && git checkout master && git branch -d `cat tmp.txt` && rm tmp.txt
```

would work, but you'd need to make sure you're not overwriting anything with the `> tmp.txt`

Comment: I'm writing the branch's name into .git/BRANCH to mimic native Git's behavior

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142066/7976758
Q: How to get the current branch name in Git?
A: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

```
[alias]
  fetch-checkout = !curbr=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && git fetch -p && git fetch origin master:master && git checkout master && git branch -D $curbr
```

Comment: I haven't tested but it should work. `git` calls `bash` anyway even on w32. There are also other unixisms both here and in the other answer — bacticks, `$()`.

Comment: this is a better answer than using a file to store the branch name as in the other answer.