# fastest possible way to get name of current branch, or an appropriate string if not on a branch

Tags: git

At the moment I use

```
git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

But it's too slow in terms of execution time.

Is there a faster way to generate the same output?

And I mean *identical* output (I haven't seen any cases I dislike), e.g. detached heads

```
(HEAD detached at SHA)
```

rebasing

```
(no branch, rebasing BRANCH)
```

etc.

---

I already tried e.g.

```
cat .git/HEAD | cut -d '/' -f3
```

but I know that sometimes, e.g. if rebasing, that won't work. Then I would have to check for existence of `.git/REBASE_HEAD` ? Also there's the problem of locating the `.git` directory from any subdirectory. In the end I don't know if a solution like this would be faster, at least probably not if I (with my inexperience) am the one to code it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current branch name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git)

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc I don't think its a duplicate, because he is asking for the fastest way to get the current branch name, whereas the other question asks for how to get this name

Comment: As a sidenote, on a detached HEAD state, your current command would *not* ouput a branch name. I guess this is out of the scope of your question?

Comment: @RomainValeri I'm not very fluent in git. I don't know what a detached HEAD state is. I will look it up now.

Comment: @minseong Simply put, you can directly checkout a commit, and then there's no current branch until you checkout a branch again. If your script has to encompass all possible cases, I thought it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: @RomainValeri my current command outputs `(HEAD detached at 755a114)`. This is desired behaviour

Comment: @minseong So it suits your needs? Fine then, sorry for the noise.

Comment: @RomainValeri no it's good noise, thank you. I like the discussion and learning (although I will delete the comments if you do)

Answer (score 3):

You also can use [git symbolic-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref). However, be careful, since this **doesn't work** when **rebasing**.

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

By the way, this is the shorter command I know to get this information (29 chars)

Comment: Doesn't work for example when rebasing. Probably because this error will have to be checked, this will end up being slower

Comment: @minseong: when you are in the middle of an interactive or failed rebase, you're not on *any* branch. `git branch` will show this too. The branch you *were* on when you started, if any—you may have started on no branch—is recorded in the information about the in-progress rebase; `git status` can retrieve it. (Edit: I see I should have read through all the collapsed comments under the question itself first :-) )

Comment: You can get the same effect as the `git branch | grep ... | cut ...` using: `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD || echo "(HEAD detached at $(git rev-parse --short HEAD))"`. The `||` means *if the left-side command failed, run the right side one.* The `-q` makes the symbolic-ref command fail quietly (no `fatal` message) and the right side command prints what `git branch` would have for the detached HEAD, using `git rev-parse --short` to get the abbreviated hash.

Comment: @torek I think the question itself also clarifies that, but yes I guess the title is still wrong I'll edit it

Comment: @torek that's true, thanks for writing that out. Unfortunately that command line is basically the same if the head is attached and it's slower when the head is detached

Comment: @minseong That's ... annoying, at least. I presume you're on Windows, where starting processes is notoriously slow. This sort of thing is nearly instantaneous on Linux.

Comment: @torek it is taking 8 milliseconds roughly. I am using zsh inside of kitty on macOS Mojave.

Comment: @torek can you build a table comparing the execution times of all options here? It will certainly be the chosen answer for this question

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) : *(but unfortunately, as for other answers, this does **not** handle the case of an in-process rebase)*

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Both `rev-parse` and `symbolic-ref` are plumbing commands, probably very close in terms of execution time.

Comment: In short, as opposed to plumbing commands, porcelain commands are intended for human consumption, plumbing commands are mainly for scripting purposes. See [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain)

Comment: when rebasing this outputs `HEAD`. I guess I can test for that output and just convert it to `(no branch, rebasing ???)` but maybe this ends up being slower.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have to absolutely use git commands, You can just read the branch name from the actual `.git` folder.

```
cat .git/HEAD | cut -d '/' -f3
```

This breaks, when you are not in any branch ( So does others ), during which it will return the SHA of the commit that you are in ( unlike the others ). I can't think of any other situation, where it may break.

Comment: Doesn't work for all cases, I would like to always have the same output that my `git branch` example would. I think this might be the way to go though

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it's that slow but you can try this. Might be equally slow.
`git status|head -n1|cut -d ' ' -f4`