# How to show a branch of git on Terminal?

Tags: git, macos

I would like to show the branch name of git on terminal.
However, I don't know how to do that.

I have installed git by homebrew.

Generally, I can see this two file on "/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/"

```
git-completion.bash git-prompt.sh
```

But they are not there...

Comment: what do you mean by "show a branch"? log the commits of a given branch? list the available branch names? get the name of the branch you are currently checked out?

Comment: I mean that we can anytime see the branch name we are using on terminal by using these things.

Comment: I use https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current branch name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+show+the+current+branch

Answer (score 2):

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

in terminal will output the name of currently checked out branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin `__git_ps1`:

If you don't have the command `__git_ps1`, then add the following line in your `.bash_profile` to source `git-completion.bash`:

```
source /path/to/git-completion.bash
```

You can find the file `git-completion.bash` using:

```
mdfind git-completion.bash
```

Once it is done, you need to add a call to `__git_ps1` in your `$PS1` variable (which defines your prompt). For that, you need to redefine the variable in your `.bash_profile`. Here is an example:

```
PS1='\h:\W \u $(__git_ps1) \$'
```

If you already defined it before (to customise it for example), you can add in it the part `$(__git_ps1)`.

Finally, restart your terminal.

As an extra, you can set in your `.bash_profile` the following:

```
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM=auto
```

The first one will allow to display a `*` if you have local modifications and a `+` if you have staged changes. The second one will allow to display a `$` if you have stashes. The third one displays info about your upstream (`>` if you are ahead and can push, `<` if you are behind and can pull, `<>` if you diverged).

It would look like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if one is missing the original __git_ps1 function from [@git/git/git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh), this one-liner can be utilized as temporary solution. just like the original, it prints current branch name like `main`, `dev` etc. or nothing, if current directory is outside of any git tree

```sh
    __git_ps1 () {
        git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | tr -d '\n'
    }
```

to get the function working everywhere in bash properly one have to add the above code to `/etc/bash.bashrc` or local `~/.bashrc` and append it with `export -f __git_ps1` command. this will make the wrapper available even after `sudo -i`

Answer (score 0):

In order to show current git branch on ubuntu terminal :

1. Open the ~/.bashrc file with your favourite editor. (I did with nano : sudo nano ~/.bashrc)
2. Then add the following script:

   ```
   git_branch() {
             git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
          }
   export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\[\033[00;32m\]\$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ "
   ```
3. Load the bashrc file to reflect the branch using `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Show git branch name
force_color_prompt=yes
color_prompt=yes
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Add this to you `~/.bashrc` files