# zsh - function parameters in captured output?

Tags: shell, zsh

I've defined a bunch of zsh aliases for compiling my projects, which will basically `cd` into my projects directory, and compile the relevant project (which I pass as an argument). Now, I want to include which branch I am building to the output of the function, but am having some difficulty in how to express that in zsh.

I tried using the following below to [grab the branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git), but to no avail.

```
function buildproject {
    echo "Building project ~/$1 $(git -C '/Users/myuser/$1' branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2)";
```

Instead, I get

> fatal: cannot change to '/Users/myuser/$1': No such file or directory

And looking at my syntax highlighting, it doesn't seem to recognize the parameter. How can I get zsh to use the parameter?

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes around any string in which you want expansion to occur.

Comment: (I closed this with a bash duplicate, but the specifically relevant subset of semantics are identical).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, interesting. I thought that the double quotes would have interfered with the echo. I guess since they're inside the $() it's different?

Comment: BTW, `grep '[*]'` is going to be a lot more reliable. Some versions will treat a single `*` as invalid regex syntax (which it is), rather than as a literal string to match.

Comment: Right, `$( ... )` opens a new quoting context.

Comment: (That's one of the things that makes `$( ... )` better than backticks; the way backticks interact with quotes, backslashes, and other syntax is... complicated).

Comment: Cool, thanks! Didn't realize that was the issue haha