# How to generically fetch just the current branch

Tags: git, git-fetch

I want to generically fetch the current branch only:

```
git fetch origin HEAD
```

but how do I determine the default remote?

```
git fetch DEFAULT_REMOTE HEAD
```

I assume HEAD is the most generic way to refer to the current branch, but I also need a generic way to refer to the default remote for the current branch?

Note that doing this:

```
git fetch HEAD
```

give me this problem:

> fatal: 'HEAD' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

```
git fetch origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

## With Generic Remote

```
git fetch $(git config --local branch.$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD).remote) $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

## Explanation

As per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) you can issue git fetch from a specific refspec.

Using the following format of `git fetch`, you can ask for a specific ref: 
`git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]`

> **< refspec >**
>
> > Specifies which refs to fetch and which local refs to update.

This subshell `$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245587/7395911).

The other one I've wrote myself and it's the following `$(git config --local branch.$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD).remote)`, it uses the first one to increase generalization, but what it does is to return the name of the remote associated with the branch in your local config, following this pattern `git config --local branch.<branch_name>.remote`.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume HEAD is the most generic way to refer to the current branch ...

It is, yes.  There's a pitfall here though, as we will see in a moment.

> but I also need a generic way to refer to the default remote for the current branch?

There are a lot of ways to do this, and each has its own possible pitfalls, but I think the simplest is to use `git config` to read back half of the current branch's *upstream* setting.

The obvious pitfall here is that the current branch may not *have* an upstream.

If you have a modern Git, `git rev-parse` can return information about the upstream of any branch, including the current branch:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
refs/heads/master
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD@{u}
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Here, the current branch is `master` and its upstream is `origin/master`.  These use the full spelling of each ref, which is a good idea if you're writing scripts, since the abbreviated names (`master` and `origin/master`) could mis-parse: e.g., `master` might turn into `refs/tags/master`, if someone has created a tag named `master`.

The upstream, if there is one—`git branch --unset-upstream master` will *remove* the upstream for `master`, for instance—is set as two parts:

```
$ git config --get branch.master.remote
origin
$ git config --get branch.master.merge
refs/heads/master
```

The `branch.master.remote` setting is precisely what you want here: the name of the remote, or in this case, `origin`.  So if you first find the current *branch name*:

```
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
master
```

you can use that to grab the appropriate remote name:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || die ...
remote=$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote) || die ...
```

You can now run:

```
$ git fetch $remote HEAD
```

But now we hit the first pitfall I mentioned:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 928, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (928/928), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (401/401), done.
remote: Total 928 (delta 601), reused 809 (delta 526)
Receiving objects: 100% (928/928), 843.84 KiB | 1.62 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (601/601), completed with 74 local objects.
From [url]
 * branch                  HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Note that, although I have a modern(ish) Git here (2.24.0), I did not get my `origin/master` updated.  To do that I must use instead:

```
$ git fetch $remote $branch
From [url]
 * branch                  master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   c7a6207591..51ebf55b93  master     -> origin/master
```

This time, my `origin/master` got updated appropriately.

**Edit:** I didn't mention it originally, but we can see here that my Git asked their Git for *their* `HEAD`.  Their `HEAD` is *their* `master`; had I been on some other branch, I would have still gotten their `HEAD`, i.e., their `master`, in my `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  So this is not merely cosmetic: you *must* feed your own Git a branch name here, rather than the symbolic name `HEAD`.  Compare with `git push`, where you can safely use `HEAD` for your side, because with `git push` it is *your* Git, not theirs, that resolves the symbolic name `HEAD` to a branch name.

#### Conclusion and one more pitfall

You should first obtain the current branch name.  Remember that this may fail: there may be no current branch name.  Then, use `git config --get` to get the *remote* part of the upstream setting.  (The remaining part requires mapping through the remote's default fetch refspec mapping, but we don't need it—`git fetch` will handle this—so don't bother picking up `branch.$branch.merge` at all.)

The last pitfall that is worth mention here is this: the sample code above uses `git config --get ... || die ...`, where `die` is (presumably) a shell function to quit the script entirely.  However, if you *don't* have an upstream set for the current branch, `git fetch` itself *won't* quit at this point.  It will simply use the hardcoded name `origin`.  So, depending on how slavishly you want to imitate raw `git fetch`, you might want:

```
remote=$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote) || remote=origin
```

instead.  Since *you* are writing the script, you get to control the edge and error cases here.