# show current git branch using the 'git branch' command

Tags: git

I have a problem when working on too many branches, it takes a lot of time to find which is the current branch I am working on right now. Is there a way to list the current branch on top of the list that shows up when using the `git branch` command?

Comment: **See Also**: [How to get the current branch name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6245570/1366033)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you just want the checked-out branch, use `git branch --show-current`.

Comment: Note: `--show-current` requires Git 2.22.0+ (not available by default on, e.g., Debian 10)

Comment: I didn't know that git has this command and used ```git branch | grep '*'```

Answer (score 12):

If the `git branch --show-current` command is not available with your Git version, you could use one of these commands instead:

```
$ git checkout master

$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
refs/heads/master
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
master

$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
master
```

cf. the official doc:

- [`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---symbolic-full-name)

  > This is similar to --symbolic, but it omits input that are not refs (i.e. branch or tag names; or more explicitly disambiguating "heads/master" form, when you want to name the "master" branch when there is an unfortunately named tag "master"), and show them as full refnames (e.g. "refs/heads/master").
- [`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref[=(strict|loose)]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---abbrev-refstrictloose)

  > A non-ambiguous short name of the objects name. […]
- [`git symbolic-ref <name>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref)

  > Given one argument, reads which branch head the given symbolic ref refers to and outputs its path, relative to the `.git/` directory. Typically you would give `HEAD` as the `<name>` argument to see which branch your working tree is on.
- [`git symbolic-ref --short <name>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref#Documentation/git-symbolic-ref.txt---short)

  > When showing the value of  as a symbolic ref, try to shorten the value, e.g. from `refs/heads/master` to `master`.

and note that the **`git rev-parse`** solution is "compatible" with **detached `HEAD` mode**, that is, if no branch is currently checked-out, and `HEAD` merely points to a SHA1 reference, the two `git rev-parse` commands considered above will just output "HEAD":

```
$ git checkout 56e23844e80e6d607ad5fa56dfeedcd70e97ee70
Note: checking out '56e23844e80e6d607ad5fa56dfeedcd70e97ee70'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
[…]

$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
HEAD
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
HEAD
$ git rev-parse HEAD
56e23844e80e6d607ad5fa56dfeedcd70e97ee70
```

Comment: Another option is '`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`.'

Comment: @RandomDSdevel indeed, but that command seems less "robust" in case of a detached HEAD: [`git checkout HEAD^{commit}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtlttypegtemegemv0998commitem) `&& git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` → `fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref`

Comment: True, but, for the OP's use case, they naturally already know they're on a branch they've checked out.

Comment: OK @RandomDSdevel: [its doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref) even says: "Typically you would give `HEAD` as the <name> argument to see which branch your working tree is on." So it could indeed be viewed as yet another alternative for the accepted answer, for older versions of Git that don't support `git branch --show-current`. BTW, feel free to propose an edit of my answer if you want.

Comment: I've just refactored my answer to also mention `git symbolic-ref` (and links to git-scm docs), thanks @RandomDSdevel for having suggested this.