# Create a Git Hook to pull data on another folder every time I push in the remote repository

Tags: bash, git, github, hook, githooks

I'm currently creating a Github repository for a better structure of my project. I want my project to be viewed by other peoples via link-only (because they don't have github), but I don't have found a solution. So I'm trying to transfer my project files in OneDrive and I have succeeded : I have git init my folder in OneDrive and I have git pull my github repository. This OneDrive folder will only receive new files, I'm updating my project with an other folder in my computer. Now, I want this procedure to be automatic every time I git push my updates to my remote repository.
I've tried to create that code (but I'm not sure if he's ok) :

```
cd "D:/Ewan/OneDrive/MyFolder" // Once I git push, I go to the folder to update it
git pull <github-repo> <my-branch>
```

I want to implement it into a git hook file, but I've now idea in which and where in the code already written...

Can you help me please ? Thanks !

PS : some hooks like post-receive are not in my .git folder.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me note that combining two different "tracking systems" (Git and OneDrive here) for the same folder is error-prone and can lead to inconsistencies ([for instance](https://community.rstudio.com/t/placing-a-github-repo-into-a-cloud-synced-folder-gdrive-dropbox-icloud-onedrive-etc/21072/2)).

So, I'd suggest you work in one Git repository **stored outside of the OneDrive folder**; this repository can be synchronized with GitHub or other remotes anytime you want, and it is then possible to ensure that *every time you pull or merge something in your local `master` branch, a Git hook also reliably copies the branch contents to your OneDrive folder*, which can then be synchronized automatically.

Regarding hooks, note that this use case can be viewed as a somewhat non-standard one, given "auto-deploy hooks" are typically used in server-side [bare](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) repositories, using a `post-receive` hook that is triggered after receiving a Push. However, it appears that from local side as well (in a non-bare repository), the [`post-merge`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook may provide a solution to address this specific use case!

In the sequel, I assume your repository is stored in `$HOME/git/project` and you want to auto-deploy its contents in `$HOME/OneDrive/MyFolder` every time you do a `git pull` or any `git merge` in the **master** branch (namely, `git pull` in feature branches won't make the hook to run).

### A comprehensive proof-of-concept of this idea

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# PoC(post-merge); see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

# Assuming the ambient Git repo is NOT a bare repo (i.e., it has a working dir)

# Get unambiguous branch name; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61808046/9164010
current_branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD)
target_branch="refs/heads/master"

# TODO: Update this variable accordingly (a trailing slash is optional here):
dest_dir="$HOME/OneDrive/MyFolder"

# Redirect output to stderr
exec 1>&2

if [ "$current_branch" != "$target_branch" ]; then
    echo "post-merge: no-op (NOT on $target_branch)"
else
    echo "post-merge: on $target_branch (in $PWD)"

    # Use mktemp + git-archive to avoid issues with a "dirty working directory"
    # as well as with files to be ignored (e.g., the .git subdirectory itself);
    # this is just ONE possible approach (which resets timestamps in $dest_dir)
    # and other ones might be considered (e.g., using "rsync --exclude-from" …)
    temp_dir=$(mktemp -d) || { echo "Failed to create tmp directory"; exit 2; }
    set -exo pipefail
    git archive --format=tar HEAD -- . | ( cd "$temp_dir/" && tar xf -)
    rsync -a --delete-delay "$temp_dir/" "$dest_dir"
    # Note that in the param $temp_dir/ above, the trailing slash is mandatory.
    rm -fr "$temp_dir"
fi
```

### Installation instructions

You'll just need to run:

```sh
touch ~/git/project/.git/hooks/post-merge
chmod a+x ~/git/project/.git/hooks/post-merge

# then edit this file with any text editor of your choice, pasting the code above
gedit ~/git/project/.git/hooks/post-merge &
```

**Disclaimer**: this Git hook relies on `bash` and `rsync` (which you may need to install beforehand); and I only tested it on GNU/Linux…

As an aside, if you need to extend or refactor this suggested shell code, I would recommend to *always run the [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) linter on your script* before using it in production.

Comment: Hello @Xeway; just curious: was you able to test this approach under Windows, and if yes, did it work for you?