# Is there a way to symbolically refer to the NAME of the current branch?

Tags: git, branch

Normally, when I "need" a branch name in the Git command line, I'll either retype the name (using auto-complete when available), or select+right-click with the mouse. This feels too slow and repetitive.

- What is a 'lazy' way to refer to the expanded NAME of the current branch in git commands?
- Is there built-in and consistent support for such, or does it require shell expansion?

Here are two example use-cases of when having the NAME is handy. I'm not looking for a git alias, unless such can be generalized to all commands. Even if the answer is "no", hints on how to improve such workflows are appreciated as secondary information - just ensure to answer the questions above first.

## Example #1

Rebase onto a different commit.

```
git checkout -b mybranch                    # on 'mybranch'
touch x; git commit -mx -- x                # on 'mybranch'

# Is is possible to avoid 'mybranch' here?
# Using HEAD will switch from 'mybranch' to a commit.
git rebase --onto otherbranch mybranch^ mybranch
```

## Example #2

Comparing the local and remote branch, assuming standard same-names.

```
# Standard way..
git diff origin/mybranch

# I often find myself wanting to do something like..
git diff origin/NAME
git log -1 origin/NAME
```

Comment: Probably duplicate-ish of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git .. which indicates "no". However, answers there might be outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, I'll edit this to add: For the *specific* case of *the upstream of the current branch* (`origin/NAME` in your `git log` example), [TTT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61963092/1256452) using `@{u}` is the way to go.  That is, if you're on your branch `xyz`, and its upstream is `origin/xyz`, you can just run:

```
git diff @{u}
```

or:

```
git log @{u}..
```

(note: some shells may require that you quote the curly brackets).

Note that if the upstream of your current branch `xyz` is `origin/abc`, `xyz@{u}` or `@{u}` means `origin/abc`, not `origin/xyz`!  This is usually what you want; using `origin/$(git command)` will as I note below will get you the other answer, i.e., `origin/xyz` instead of `origin/abc` for this case.

The upstream of a (local) branch *can* be another (local) branch: if the upstream of your current brnch `xyz` is your own branch `ghi`, `@{u}` is just a way of writing `ghi` without having to think about it.  And of course, your current branch must have an upstream set.

Each of your branch names can have at most one upstream: you either have one, or you have none.  To set a new upstream, use `git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream`.  To remove the upstream entirely (though there's rarely any reason for that), use `git branch --unset-upstream`.  Both commands can take a branch name as well; both operate, by default, on the current branch.

#### The general case

> What is a 'lazy' way to refer to the expanded NAME of the current branch in git commands?

There is a way, but it's terrible: use the word `HEAD`.

The reason it is terrible is that it works for some commands and not for others:

> Is there built-in and consistent support for such, or does it require shell expansion?

To make it work for *all* commands, you need shell expansion.

Essentially, whenever Git looks up the name `HEAD`, it can do that with one of two questions:

1. What branch name does `HEAD` refer to?

   These four commands all do mostly the same job, in slightly different ways:<sup>1</sup>

   ```
   git symbolic-ref HEAD
   git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
   git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
   git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
   ```

   Other Git commands will sometimes internally use one of these commands, or an equivalent, to find the branch name.
2. What *commit* (hash ID) does `HEAD` refer to?

   The command:

   ```
   git rev-parse HEAD
   ```

   asks and answers this question.

   Other Git commands sometimes internally do this as well.

As a rather interesting example, the `git push` command asks *both* questions:

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```

will look up the *name*, as if by `git symbolic-ref HEAD`, and then also look up the *hash ID*, as if by `git rev-parse HEAD`, and will run the equivalent of the shell-expanded command:

```
git push -u origin $(git rev-parse HEAD):$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)
```

If you need to control *which* expansion occurs, explicitly, you'll have to use your own `$(git ...)` command in the right place in your shell command.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git symbolic-ref` variants produce the full or abbreviated branch name but *fail* when you are in detached-HEAD mode.  The `git rev-parse` variants produce the full or abbreviated branch name but simply print `HEAD` when you are in detached-HEAD mode.

Comment: I took a different approach with my answer because I felt the goal was more about less typing. But I just learned quite a bit from your answer, so thank you. +1

Comment: @TTT: that's a good point: I added a lot more including a link to your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

These two shorthands almost get you what you want:

```
@    # this is the same as writing HEAD
@{u} # this is the same writing origin/{your-branch-name}
```

With this you can achieve Example 2 with simply:

```
git diff @{u}
git log -1 @{u}
```

Example 1 is tougher, because as you point out, HEAD will detach during rebase. But it isn't really that big of a deal if you detach, because you can easily recover:

```
git rebase --onto otherbranch @^ @ # detached on a new commit
git checkout -B mybranch # reset mybranch to point to the current commit
```

The nice thing about the @ symbol is it's easy to type in conjunction with the ^ and ~ characters. For example, if you have 5 commits you want to move onto another branch instead of just 1, @~5 is nearly as easy to type as @^.