# Batch file to add git branch into header file

Tags: git, batch-file, pre-build-event

I'm working on a C project, under git, and I would like to add the branch name into an header file.

This is my idea:

I have a version header file:

```
/* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/ 
#ifndef _VERSION_INTERFACE_H_
#define _VERSION_INTERFACE_H_
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported defines ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported types ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported constants --------------------------------------------------------*/
const char *gitBranch = "develop";
/* Exported macro ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported functions --------------------------------------------------------*/ 
#endif  /* _VERSION_INTERFACE_H_ */
```

and I would like to replace the string associated to gitBranch with the name of the current branch.
In this way I can execute the batch file during the pre-build process and update the gitBranch variable.

I write a first version of a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET GIT_CMD="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"

rem Specify input file name
SET inputFileName=include\version_interface.h

rem String to find
SET stringToFind=const char *gitBranch

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ( '"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" branch --show-current' ) do SET branchName=%%a

rem String to replace
SET stringToReplace=%branchName%

for /F "tokens=*" %%n in (!infile!) do (
SET LINE=%%n
SET TMPR=!LINE:%stringToFind%=%stringToReplace%!
Echo !TMPR!>>tmp.txt
)

move tmp.txt %infile%
pause
```

but at the moment I cannot:

- Update the branch name inside the header file.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Best regards,
Federico

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current branch name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git)

Comment: No, because I need suggestion about how to write a batch script to do that

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` works fine in bash context. Is it more generally about bash syntax?

Comment: Yes, my question is about the bash sintax.

Comment: If your question is about `bash`, the 'nix Bourne Again SHell, why have you written a Windows Cmd shell script _(batch file)_?

Comment: It was a typo, if you read the code you can understand that is code for Cmd shell

Comment: If you're working on a `C` 'programming' project, why use inferior 'scripting' to perform a task you should be able to perform in that language?

Comment: Because I'm writing code for an embedded system that cannot have access to git. So I need a script to modify an header file used by the compiler. In that way my embedded system can communicate which code is running.

Comment: You don't need access to git, what I'm telling you is it would make more sense to write a small find and replace C program to do this task, not trying to use a batch script for programming, when it was only designed to execute a series of simple commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested. Just make sure you add the correct file path to `set infile=`

```
@echo off
set "infile=C:\Path\to\FILE.h"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" branch --show-current' ) do set "branchName=%%a"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%infile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%infile%') do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=%%i"
    set "line=!line:*]=!"
    if "!line:~0,21!" == "const char *gitBranch" set "line=const char *gitBranch ="%branchName%";"
    echo(!line!>>!infile!
    endlocal
 )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm!!! It is what I'm looking for!