# Get the name of running branch on an equipment

Tags: git, ipc

I am currently working on IPC (industrial PC) of production line with some equipment and machines.
just wondering to know how to get the name of running branch on each machine?
for example I have 5 different branches for an specific machine and just need to know which one is running on machine now.

Answer (score -1):

The following command displays the current branch, without the others:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Comment: Do not [copy answers from others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142066/1293244).

Comment: I didn't copy, I have it as an alias on my computer