# Bash: Execute git command in .bashrc failing

Tags: bash, git, function

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245587/15528750) states that to find out the current branch name of a git repo, we can do

```bash
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Now, this works for me, and I want to use this command when pushing to git, i.e. I want first to find out the branch name and then push to that branch, so I wrote the following bash function into my `.bashrc` file:

```bash
function bname() {
        branch="git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
        command git push origin "$branch"
}
```

After doing `source .bashrc`, executing typing `bname` in the terminal results in

```bash
fatal: invalid refspec 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'
```

How do I need to modify my bash function? Thanks.

EDIT: To exectute the command `branch`, I tried sth like this:

```bash
function bname() {
        branch= command "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
        command git push origin $branch
}
```

but this results in the error

```bash
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD: command not found
[...]
```

Comment: You're storing the string with the command in the variable - not running it.

Comment: cf. the edit I made

Comment: Same issue - you have to run the rev-parse commandi n a subscell if you want to store the output of the command.

Comment: could you quickly post an answer?

Comment: Why do you need this command? `git push origin HEAD` does the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the output of a command to be saved in a variable you need to use [subshells](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html)

For example:

```
variable=$( ls )
```

would store the output written by `ls` to stdout in the indicated variable.

Comment: its good practice to surround that with double quotes

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         branch="git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
> ```

You should be using [*command substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
```

Bash will run the command within `$(...)` and replace with the command's output.  Incidentally, these days the `$(...)` format is preferred to backticks.

> EDIT: To exectute the command branch, I tried sth like this:
> ...
>
> ```
> branch= command "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
> ```

You really can't guess your way through bash syntax.  I highy recommend you read a tutorial or two.