# Git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD vs branch --show-current differences in a new init project

Tags: git, branch, git-rev-parse

I took an empty project with just one newly created file, I ran the `git init` command, when I run the commands below I get the following results:

command:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

output:

```
HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

command:

```
git branch --show-current
```

output:

```
main
```

I wonder what the correct command in this case to execute, what the correct name of the branch in the current state `HEAD` or `main`?

What is the difference between the two commands?

Comment: There are many ways to get the name of the current branch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-do-i-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git/12142066#12142066 `git describe --all`, `git name-rev --name-only HEAD`, `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` and they give slightly different results and different errors because you can be in different situations: a newborn branch (no commit), detached `HEAD` (you're not on any branch at all).

Comment: `git describe --all` -> `fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.`
`git name-rev --name-only HEAD` -> `Could not get sha1 for HEAD. Skipping.`
`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` -> `main

Comment: Exactly that: different results and different errors.

Comment: In this case when there are no commits or if there are commits, what command would you recommend using?

Comment: If you're not on any branch (no commits or detached `HEAD`) what answer do you want for the question "what is the current branch?"? For me any error is good enough. `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` returning `master` is a kind of lie; it is not the current branch, it's the future branch, the branch that will be created when you'll do the 1st commit. if this lie is ok this is the command.

Comment: On detached `HEAD` no command could return the branch — there is no the pointing branch; some return error and some return the commit the `HEAD` points to; in that case `git branch --points-at=HEAD` returns **a list** of branches to which the commit belong.

Answer (score 4):

**Root cause:** Your `main` branch is in fact *[unborn](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefunbornaunborn)* here.

---

To give a bit more details,

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref <ref>
```

tries to recursively search **for the commit hash** ultimately sitting behind `<ref>` (which could point to another ref).

In the case of your empty repo, `git init` has already created a `.git/HEAD` file, which you can read with `cat .git/HEAD` which will output `ref: refs/heads/main` (for some people it might also be `ref: refs/heads/master`, depending on the config).

However, it's only a temporary ref put in place at repo creation by default. Your first commit will be, unless you explicitly checkout a new branch, on this first default ref.

And regardless of what's written in `HEAD`, `.git/refs/heads/main` doesn't already exist until you commit something to it.

The reason `git branch --show-current` doesn't "fail" but outputs `main` is that it does *not* dereference the branch name until commit hash, it **only needs a ref name**, and finds it in `HEAD`, unbothered by the emptiness of the ref it actually points to.

Comment: I will try to explain this answer in simpler terms (hopefully without adding errors): a *reference* is a human-friendly way to refer to a commit hash. A *head* is a type of ref that points to the tip of a branch, and *HEAD* is the head that points to the tip of the current branch. `git init` creates a branch, and so HEAD points to its tip. But since there are no commits, if you try to _dereference_ it (get the underlying commit hash), it will fail. Until you create your first commit.

Comment: If I do something like this:
`echo "# testnode" >> README.md`
`git init`
`git add .`
`git commit -m "first commit"`

Skipping the step to `git branch -M nameBranch` creates the default one which can be `master`, `main` or something else?

Comment: So what would be the correct name from which command?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. `git init` creates a branch with the default branch name (`master`, or something else you can define).