# How do I create a Bash alias?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm on OSX and I need to put something like this, `alias blah="/usr/bin/blah"` in a config file but I don't know where the config file is.

Comment: Tangentially, this particular alias is basically redundant unless you are specifically trying to override he shell's `PATH` resolution for this specific command. If `/usr/bin` is in your `PATH` (which really it must be) then `blah` will run from there just fine without this alias, too, unless there is also say `/usr/local/bin/blah` and `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` *but* you still want to prefer `/usr/bin/blah` and cannot for some reason simply remove or rename `/usr/local/bin/blah`.

Comment: Even then this is a dubious, hackish solution which should come with a big fat ugly comment with a warning message telling you how this will bite your shapely lower abdomen, and another saying "I told you so" for each time this happened.

Comment: For all the automation lovers: I personally add 

`addAlias() { echo "alias $1='$2' " >> ~/.bash_profile`

 to my bash_profile and then I source it and run 
`addAlias hi 'echo "hi" '`
. Source bash profile and type `hi` to see it.

Comment: Make sure to escape characters properly alias name=" echo "string" " is wrong, but alias name=" echo \"string\" " will be fine.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You can add an `alias` or a `function` in your startup script file.

### MacOS 10.13 High Sierra and earlier:

The default shell is bash.  Usually the startup script file is `.bashrc`, `.bash_login` or `.profile` file in your home directory.

Since these files are hidden you will have to do an `ls -a` to list them. If you don't have one you can create one.

---

If I remember correctly, when I had bought my Mac, the `.bash_login` file wasn't there. I had to create it for myself so that I could put `prompt info`, `alias`, `functions`, etc. in it.

Here are the steps if you would like to create one:

1. Start up Terminal
2. Type `cd ~/` to go to your home folder
3. Type `touch .bash_profile` to create your new file.
4. Edit `.bash_profile` with your favorite editor (or you can just type `open -e .bash_profile` to open it in TextEdit.
5. Type `. .bash_profile` to reload `.bash_profile` and update any alias you add.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @jaypal! Is the command `source .bash_profile` an alternative to step 5?

Comment: Yes on my OSX Mavericks there was no `.bash_profile` in my home dir. Creating it, adding the alias to it, and then initiating it with the `. .bash_profile` command worked.

Comment: .bash_profile works for me! :) .bashrc didn't on El Capitan

Comment: On OSX El Capitan `.bash_profile` works. If it doesn’t automatically load when you open a terminal window, it is probably because it was created without executable permission. This command will fix it and it should automatically load for future sessions: `chmod u+x .bash_profile`

Comment: .bash_profile profile is locked how can i update this file

Comment: Thanks! Worked on Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: To get aliases working on High Sierra, I had to add `source ~/.bashrc` to `.bash_profile`, as instructed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/902955/4039886

Comment: Just a little comment here. You need to close entirely your terminal and reopen to make it work properly 

Comment: A little bit of additional information on the above, If you want to add your aliases in the .bashrc file, make sure you add "source .bashrc" in the .bash_profile file and reload it after adding.

Comment: Just in case it's still not working, restarting the tab alone won't work, we have to restart the terminal - For Dumbos like me :)

Comment: This no longer works, should create `.zshrc` file

Answer (score 87):

I just open zshrc with sublime, and edit it.

```
subl .zshrc
```

And add this on sublime:

```
alias blah="/usr/bin/blah"
```

Run this command in terminal:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Done.

Comment: This is confused. If your shell is Bash, many other answers on this page are more detailed and helpful. If you use Zsh instead of Bash, then obviously you should `source .zshrc` at the end to load in the changes you made into your currently running shell instance.

Answer (score 45):

### MacOS 10.15 Catalina and Above

Apple [switched](https://web.archive.org/web/20190826201542/https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/4/18651872/apple-macos-catalina-zsh-bash-shell-replacement-features) their default shell to **zsh**, so the config files include `~/.zshenv` and `~/.zshrc`.  This is just like `~/.bashrc`, but for zsh.  Just edit the file and add what you need; it should be sourced every time you open a new terminal window:

`nano ~/.zshenv`
`alias py=python`

Then do ctrl+x, y, then enter to save.

This file seems to be executed no matter what (login, non-login, or script), so seems better than the `~/.zshrc` file.

### MacOS 10.13 High Sierra and earlier

The default shell is bash, and you can edit the file `~/.bash_profile` and add aliases:

`nano ~/.bash_profile`
`alias py=python`

Then ctrl+x, y, and enter to save.  See [this post](https://superuser.com/a/244990/435890) for more on these configs.  It's a little better to set it up with your alias in `~/.bashrc`, then source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile`.  In `~/.bash_profile` it would then look like:

`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: This should be higher now that Catalina is the most up to date Mac OS

Answer (score 33):

On OS X you want to use ~/.bash_profile. This is because by default Terminal.app opens a login shell for each new window.

See more about the different configuration files and when they are used here:
[What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

and in relation to OSX here: [About .bash_profile, .bashrc, and where should alias be written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902946/about-bash-profile-bashrc-and-where-should-alias-be-written-in)

Answer (score 21):

In my `.bashrc` file the following lines were there by default:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Hence, in my platform `.bash_aliases` is the file used for aliases by default (and the one I use). I'm not an OS X user, but I guess that if you open your `.bashrc` file, you'll be able to identify what's the file commonly used for aliases in your platform.

Comment: If the profile doesn’t automatically load when you open a terminal window, it is probably missing the executable permission. This command will fix it and it should automatically load for future sessions: `chmod u+x .bash_profile`

Comment: @Mischinab No, the file just needs to be readable in order for Bash to read it as its configuration file. Making it executable is technically harmless but unnecessary. I would discourage it on nontechnical grounds (you might end up confusing yourself and/or others).

Answer (score 18):

### It works for me on macOS Mojave

You can do a few simple steps:

1. open terminal
2. `sudo nano /.bash_profile`
3. add your aliases, as example:

```
    # some aliases
    alias ll='ls -alF'
    alias la='ls -A'
    alias eb="sudo nano ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile"
    #docker aliases
    alias d='docker'
    alias dc='docker-compose'
    alias dnax="docker rm $(docker ps -aq)"
    #git aliases
    alias g='git'
    alias new="git checkout -b"
    alias last="git log -2"
    alias gg='git status'
    alias lg="git log --pretty=format:'%h was %an, %ar, message: %s' --graph"
    alias nah="git reset --hard && git clean -df"
    alias squash="git rebase -i HEAD~2"
```

4. `source /.bash_profile`

Done. Use and enjoy!

Comment: My aliases do not work with double dashes -- in case of git. How did you get them to work? For example your `alias lg` has double dashes. I'm trying to set `alias stash="git stash --include-untracked"` but when I call it in terminal it ignores the -- command.

Comment: Just in case it's still not working, restarting the tab alone won't work, we have to restart the terminal - For Dumbos like me :)

Comment: `alias nah="git reset --hard && git clean -df"` is the winner of the most intuitive naming contest!

Answer (score 13):

For macOS Catalina Users:

Step 1: create or update .zshrc file

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

Step 2: Add your alias line

```
alias blah="/usr/bin/blah"
```

Step 3: Source .zshrc

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Step 4: Check you're alias, by typing alias on the command prompt

```
alias
```

Answer (score 9):

```
cd /etc
sudo vi bashrc
```

Add the following like:

```
alias ll="ls -lrt"
```

Finally restart Terminal.

Comment: After adding alias. Run 'source' on your '.bash_profile' file.
Ex: source ~/.bash_profile (command which activates/ reloads the bash aliases)

Answer (score 7):

The config file for scripts and programs is `~/.bashrc` and the config file that gets loaded when you use Terminal is `~/.bash_login`.

I think the best way is to just have everything in `~/.bashrc`.

For your specific question just enter (this will overwrite any existing ~/.bashrc):

```
echo "alias blah=\"/usr/bin/blah\"" >>~/.bashrc
```

into the Terminal and a `~/.bashrc` file will be created with your new alises. After that just edit the file to add new aliases, functions, settings etc.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `>>` instead of `>` so that it appends to the file rather than replacing everything in it?

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to home
2. Open .bashrc
3. Create alias at bottom of the file

   ```
   alias alias_name='command to do'
   eg: alias cdDesktop='cd /Desktop'
   ```
4. Save the file
5. source .bashrc

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
6. Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) & type cdDesktop & press enter

Answer (score 4):

If you put `blah="/usr/bin/blah"` in your `~/.bashrc` then you can use `$blah` in your login shell as a substitute for typing `/usr/bin/blah`

Comment: The dollar sign is emphatically not in any way necessary, useful, or correct here.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to edit the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

I need to run the Postgres database and created an alias for the purpose. The work through is provided below:

```
$ nano ~/.bash_profile 

# in the bash_profile, insert the following texts:

alias pgst="pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start"
alias pgsp="pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop"


$ source ~/.bash_profile 

### This will start the Postgres server 
$ pgst

### This will stop the Postgres server 
$ pgsp
```

Answer (score 1):

### I think it's proper way:

1) Go to teminal. `open ~/.bashrc`. Add if not exists

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

2) `open ~/.bash_aliases`. If not exists: `touch ~/.bash_aliases && open ~/.bash_aliases`

3) To add new alias rather
- edit `.bash_aliases` file and restart terminal or print `source ~/.bash_aliases`
- print `echo "alias clr='clear'" >> ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases` where your alias is `alias clr='clear'`.

4) Add line `source ~/.bash_aliases` to `~/.bash_profile` file. It needs to [load aliases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23827) in each init of terminal.

Answer (score 1):

create a bash_profile at your user root - ex

```
/user/username/.bash_profile
```

open file

vim ~/.bash_profile

add alias as ex. (save and exit)

```
alias mydir="cd ~/Documents/dirname/anotherdir"
```

in new terminal just type mydir - it should open

```
/user/username/Documents/dirname/anotherdir
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a permanent alias shortcut, put it in .bash_profile file and point .bashrc file to .bash_profile file.  Follow these steps (I am creating an alias command called bnode to run babel transpiler on ES6 code):

1. Go to terminal command prompt and type “cd”  (this will take
   you to the home directory.  Note: even though your programming files may
   be located on your “D: drive”, your “.bash” files may be located on
   your “C: drive” )
2. To see the location of the home directory, type “pwd”  (this will show you the home directory path and where the .bash files are probably located)
3. To see all dot "." files in the home directory, type “ls -la”  (this will show ALL files including hidden dot "." files)
4. You will see 2 files: “.bash_profile” and “.bashrc”
5. Open .bashrc file in VS Code Editor or your IDE and enter “source ~/.bash_profile” in first line (to point .bashrc file to .bash_profile)
6. Open .bash_profile file in VS Code Editor and enter “alias bnode='./node_modules/.bin/babel-node'” (to create permanent bnode shortcut to execute as bash command)
7. Save and close both files
8. Now open the file you want to execute (index.js) and open in terminal command prompt and run file by using command “bnode index.js”
9. Now your index.js file will execute but before creating bnode alias in .bash_profile file you would get the error "bash: bnode command not found" and it would not recognize and give errors on some ES6 code.
10. Helpful link to learn about dotfiles: https://dotfiles.github.io/

I hope this helps!  Good luck!