# module installed by pip is found in pip2 list but not in pip list

Tags: python, pip

I am totally confused on the relation between pip and python versions. I am using ubuntu 15.10

I gave `locate /usr/bin/pip` I have got the following response.

```
/usr/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip2
/usr/bin/pip3
```

I installed pyLDAvis module using- `pip install pyldavis`
But I never see pyldavis module in `pip list` and when I say `import pyLDAvis` it throws me error saying `no module named pyLDAvis`

After spending much time I have found this module in `pip2 list`.

1. When I installed it using `pip` why did it install for python2.7 and
   why it's located in pip2 list and why not in pip list?
2. If we have only 2 python versions- python 2.x(pip2) and python
       3.x(pip3)  what's all this confusion with three executables for  python and pip each- `python, python2.7, python3.5 and pip, pip2, pip3`? Please provide any background information and the main reason for this.
3. My existing python scripts are unable to run because the module is accessible by `python2.7` and not by `python` Do I now need to point(using symbolic link) python to python2.7 ? If yes do I need to install all the modules that I have installed using pip again with pip2 so that pip2 list
   has all the modules that were there for pip list earlier?

Comment: Can you do `ls -l /usr/bin/{pip,python}*` and tell us what it says?

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37586175/6598100) (from a related question); your pip can apparently point to the wrong Python. That might be a partial answer, for number 1 on your list.

Comment: It gave me a long list https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LZHER5HBszN1RjVnJhUFN1MkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have multiple versions of Python installed (system 2 and 3, plus others), and I never use the `pip` command, because, depending on which version of Python upgraded pip (the module) last, it could point anywhere. Instead, use `pip2` for Python 2, `pip3` for Python 3. You somehow have Python 3.4 and 3.5 installed, so you'll need to examine the first line of `/usr/bin/pip3` to see which version it's pointing to.