# virtualenvwrapper.sh crashes shell

Tags: python, python-3.6, virtualenvwrapper

I am following the install instructions for `virtualenvwrapper`, described [here](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file).

I have used `pip install virtualenvwrapper` and it installed at the path `/home/.pyenv/shims/`.

But when I run the command 
`source /home/.pyenv/shims/virtualenvwrapper.sh` the whole Konsole shuts down.
I had previously put the command in the `.bashrc` file and almost broke Linux because the Konsole would crash immediately after opening.

I'm using Linux OpenSuse and Python version 3.6.0.

Any ideas what could be causing the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come across this problem several times now on different machines and while I don't fully understand why it happens, I have found a solution to the problem.

The problem seems to be due to mismatches in the `python` version being used and the `pip` version used to install `virtualenvwrapper`. I had been using the system install of python (2.7) but the pip version was for python 3.5.

To fix this, use the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311336/pip-suddenly-using-wrong-version-of-python) as follows:

```
python -m pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Then you can `source /path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh` and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution.

`source ~/.pyenv/versions/VERSION/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` works every time.

You can't use the shims directory for some reason.  Maybe since virtualenvwrapper was likely installed into the pyenv version directory.  If you use the shims directory, that link could break when switching versions with pyenv.  It's better to access it directly.

Comment: I have no such file

Comment: @qaispak did you replace `VERSION` to your corresponding version like `3.9.1`?

Comment: This worked for me after changing the VERSION to my corresponding version. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I'm seeing the same thing on MacOS (10.12.6).

For me the .zshrc entry which closes/ends the terminal window is:

```
source $HOME/.pyenv/shims/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I also would like to know why this is occurring, and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have exactly the same problem on MacOS (10.15.1)

Comment: I did not. I gave up on using virtualenvwrapper, and started using pipenv.  I didn’t have the time to figure out what was going on, and went with a different tool.

Comment: Had the same issue, found this article very helpful: https://opensource.com/article/19/6/python-virtual-environments-mac. It helped me out at least

Answer (score 2):

[Sean Combs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538896/sean-combs)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65866266/2340709) works for me, too. But I didn't want to hard code a specific python version, so I use `grep` to build the path to `virtualenvwrapper.sh` dynamically.

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$HOME/.pyenv/shims/python
source $HOME/.pyenv/versions/$($VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON -V 2>&1 | grep -Po '(?<=Python )(.+)')/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: This worked for me. I did however have to adapt the dynamic grab of the current Python version so leaving this here in case it helps the next person: `source $HOME/.pyenv/versions/$($VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON -V 2>&1 | cut -d' ' -f2)/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65866266/4586186) since I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, adding

```
export PYENV_VERSION="$(pyenv version-name)"
source ~/.pyenv/versions/$PYENV_VERSION/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

to your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc` in my case) allows you to point to the correct `virtualenvwrapper.sh` even if you change python versions without hardcoding or grep

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Mac and I found that zsh crashes
with line
`source ~/.pyenv/versions/$PYENV_VERSION/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`
if you not specified `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` variable

So this's my .zshrc (or .bashrc) config for pyenv and virtualenvwrapper on fresh user

```
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

export PYENV_VERSION="$(pyenv version-name)"
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$HOME/.pyenv/shims/python"


export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel

source ~/.pyenv/versions/$PYENV_VERSION/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# Tell pyenv-virtualenvwrapper to use pyenv when creating new Python environments
export PYENV_VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PREFER_PYVENV="true"

# Set the pyenv shims to initialize
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, and I solved it by installing `virtualenvwrapper` with **builtin python**(e.g. /usr/bin/python3), not a pyenv python runtime, though the builtin one is not used in actual workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

In your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`, putting:

```
export PYENV_VERSION="$(cat $HOME/.pyenv/version)"
source "$HOME/.pyenv/versions/$PYENV_VERSION/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
```

works for me.