# macos: pip trying to find python 3.6 instead of 2.7 or 3.7 installed

Tags: python, macos, pip

When I run `pip`, I get this message:

```
$ pip
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Run `type pip` to see which file/script/alias you are actually running, then edit that file and correct it.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311336/pip-suddenly-using-wrong-version-of-python

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks! I had it working by replacing `#!/usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6` by `#!/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python`