# Created python package script not appearing to be installed

Tags: python, macos, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I'm on MacOSX (12.0.1) and with Python 3.9. I want to create a simple python package for personal use. Upon creating the package using `python setup.py install`, almost everything works: I can import the package when using python, etc. However, I've tried to follow every tutorial online to create an associated executable script. I.e., a command that I can execute from the shell that contains some functionality from the package I made. However, nothing has worked.

My setup.py code:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_package',
      version='1.0.0',
      description='heeheehoohoo',
      author='Me',
      author_email='me@me',
      url='me.com',
      packages=['my_package'],
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': ['mypkg=my_package:run']},
      install_requires=['cairosvg',
                        'selenium',
                        'PyPDF2',
      ],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False
     )
```

And under `my_package/__init__.py` I have:

```
from . mine import main

def run():
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog = 'eeeeeee', description = 'eeeeee')

    parser.add_argument('eeeeee', help = 'eeeeeee')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(f'eeeee ...')
    main(args.eeeeeee)
    print(f'Success!')
```

Everything gets installed, yet for some reason when I try to execute `$ mypkg`, I get `zsh: command not found: mypkg`. From python, I can import the function and directly try to execute `run()`. And strangest of all, each tutorial I have seen that has done anything like this can execute the commands without a problem once they'd executed `python setup.py install`.

Thank you!

---

Setting pip to the respective version of python and using `pip install .` instead of `python setup.py install` did the trick. However, it's still strange that `python setup.py install` does not work...

Comment: This seems all correct to me. Maybe it is an issue with the `PATH` environment variable. Have you checked that it contains the directory where `mypkg` has been installed? Do you know where `mypkg` has been installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip suddenly using wrong version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311336/pip-suddenly-using-wrong-version-of-python)

Comment: Yes and no. I thought about @sinoroc 's comment and I tried to identify the respective paths. At that point, I decided to look into why my pip was also displaced. After searching for a bit, the answer in that page resolved the issue for me. However, it seems to only work with `pip install .`, and not 'python setup.py install'. So as far as I am concerned, I'm happy it works. Nevertheless, I'm still confused why 'python setup.py install' does not work.

Comment: @MaxL Could you please not add [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75090598/4) in the question? Please add those details in the answer instead that you have written below.