# Switching python versions on terminal

Tags: python, terminal

While trying to install a ch38 whl file on python, I saw the version didn't match. When I enter

`C:\python` it says I have 3.7.5 as my default python. However, I want 3.8.1 as my default. I know I have it installed because when I enter in `C:\py - 0`, I have both versions.

Anyone know how to specify the version I on the terminal or set the default "python" on terminal as 3.8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch Python versions in Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354382/how-to-switch-python-versions-in-terminal)

Comment: You should check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

When you write python in the terminal, the OS looks up the program from the paths given in the PATH environment variable.

If you want to run the python interpreter with the version of 3.8.1, you need to either set the PATH environment variable to the directory where the other python interpreter is, or you can run it directly by giving the full path to that interpreter.

I'd love to help more, but I need to know on which OS you're working, and how you've installed the python interpreters.

Best of luck :)