# How to run python from /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin/

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, installation, homebrew

This morning, I attempted to uninstall both versions of python3 that I had on my system. 3.7.*something* and 3.6.5_1. After reinstalling using brew, I attempted to use `brew switch python 3.6.5_1`. All seems well but when I launch python using `python3`, it launches python 3.7.2 (which I have not explicitly installed). Additionally, when I type `which python` the output is `/user/bin/python`. Python3 does appear to be installed in `/user/local/bin` but is not being used. I think this is my problem, but it could also be something else.

Comment: This depends on your PATH environment variable.

Comment: This link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354382/how-to-switch-python-versions-in-terminal

Comment: @AKX I have PATH set to "/user/local/bin:$PATH" in my .bash_profile. Is that correct?

Comment: You probably mean `/usr/local/bin`, not `/user...` with an e in there. If that's already so, you may need to close your terminal and reopen it, or log out and back in again.

Comment: @Deb I don't believe this answers my question because this relates to changing from the default python 2.7 on MacOS to the installed version. My system is defaulting to a different version of Python3 than the one that I installed.

Comment: @AKX Yes, I meant "/usr/". It is set correctly in my .bash_profile and was before I started this process. Restarting the terminal/logging in again doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: "when I launch python using python3, it launches python 3.7.2 (which I have not explicitly installed)" what is the output of `which python3`?