# How to deal with 'no module named pygame' when pygame is installed?

Tags: pip, pygame

I am running python3.8 and i have 'import pygame' in the .py file and it says when I run it, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'" but on the terminal, I entered "python -m pip install --user pygame" and it says, " Requirement already satisfied: pygame in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.9.6)."

Now, it says python 2.7, but when I go and run " pip install pygame " presumably for python3.8, it throws an error:

> Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c
> 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-2uujwl1k/pygame/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-2uujwl1k/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> /private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-record-ceom_msx/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame
> cwd: /private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-2uujwl1k/pygame/
> Complete output (213 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/draw_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> copying src_py/*dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
> copying src_py/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
> copying src_py/threads/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/rwobject_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/pixelcopy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/overlay_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/scrap_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/touch_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/imageext_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/pixelarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/mouse_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/imageext_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/touch_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/rect_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/scrap_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/overlay_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/key_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/mixer_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/constants_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/mixer_music_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/sndarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/version_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/joystick_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/midi_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/fastevent_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/mask_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/midi_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/math_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/**main**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/mixer_music_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/sndarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/test_test*.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> copying test/test_utils/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
> copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
> copying test/run_tests__tests/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
> copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
> copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
> copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
> copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
> copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
> copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
> copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
> copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
> copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
> copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
> copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
> copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
> copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
> copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
> copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
> copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
> copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_1_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
> copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
> copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
> copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
> copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
> copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
> copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
> copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
> copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
> copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
> copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
> copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
> copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
> copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
> copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
> copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
> copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/invisible_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
> copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
> copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
> copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
> copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
> copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
> copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
> copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/incomplete_todo_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
> copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
> copying docs/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
> copying docs/**main**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/audiocapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/blit_blends.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/textinput.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/arraydemo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/blend_fill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/fonty.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/headless_no_windows_needed.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/fastevents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/prevent_display_stretching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/glcube.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/aliens.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/freetype_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/scaletest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/video.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/eventlist.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/scrap_clipboard.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/oldalien.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
> running build_ext
> building 'pygame.gfxdraw' extension
> creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
> creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c
> creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/SDL_gfx
> gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src_c/gfxdraw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/gfxdraw.o
> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
> ---
> For help with compilation see:
> https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
> To contribute to pygame development see:
> https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
> ---
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c
> 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-2uujwl1k/pygame/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-install-2uujwl1k/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> /private/var/folders/g9/77451rtd0vj7grc2_lz66tc80000gn/T/pip-record-ceom_msx/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame
> Check the logs for full command output.

Any help?

Comment: check which version is running in your terminal by typing python. Its possible that if you recently upgraded to 3.8 from 3.7 your pygame is installed for 3.7

Comment: Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: You are using python 2.7. Change that to your current version i.e 3.8 by navigating to its location and then install it

Comment: how do i change the current version (i.e. how to navigate to its location)?

Comment: You can look it up on the net or see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354382/how-to-switch-python-versions-in-terminal

Comment: It works, thank so much Rishi!

Comment: Had to use an earlier version (3.7) as 3.8 is filled with errors, but your method works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Pygame is currently downloaded onto a different version of python than the one you are using. You will have to navigate to you current python version from your terminal and then pip install it. The following link can help you navigate to your current python version [How to switch Python versions in Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354382/how-to-switch-python-versions-in-terminal).