# How do you program Mac Terminal to shorten commands

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Suppose you have to write several commands all beginning with 'python manage.py' but you do not want to write those words each and every time.  How do you create an alias where 'python manage.py' is shortened to two letters?  So what I would like is to input 'pm'.  And then I can input a command such as 'runserver'.  This would then activate: 'python manage.py runserver'?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put alias pm='your commands' in your .bash_profile in thw user directory, then command source .bash_profile

Comment: See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967843/how-do-i-create-a-bash-alias

Comment: Although I'm not entirely convinced you need an alias for this.. I usually find tab completion and cycling through previous commands suffices (especially if you have something like vim keybindings to make use of). I feel like aliases should be *generally* applicable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an alias with the name 'pm'

Open .bash_profile from your home folder. Create one if not present

Append

```
alias pm='python manage.py'
```

to the file.

Type `. .bash_profile`to load the changes

Comment: Aliases are quite limited compared to shell functions. If you use `pm() { python manage.py "$@"; }` instead, then you can export it to child processes with `export -f pm`, and you can extend it to have more complex logic.

Comment: ...for instance, if you want `runserver` to be the default command, you can't do that with an alias, but with a function, you could write `pm() { (( $# )) || set -- runserver; python manage.py "$@"; }`, such that `pm` will run `python manage.py runserver`, but `pm shell` will run `python manage.py shell`.