# Change git command for example git push like gp or other shortform

Tags: git, git-alias

Now i use ubntu 17.10.

How to change git command for example

- `git add .` command like `ga`,
- `git commit` command like `gc`
- `git push` commans lije `gp

other example like 
$ git add command like $ ga

when i typing ga then it work like git add

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I alias commands in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Bash alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967843/how-do-i-create-a-bash-alias)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using Git aliases e.g.

```
git config --global alias.co checkout
```

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

To achieve exactly what you want you can use bash aliases

in your bash prompt type

```
alias ga="git add ."
```

This will only be valid until you close your shell. To have your aliases be persistent add them to your ~/.profile file.

```
echo 'alias ga="git add ."' >> ~/.profile
```

Ubuntu uses ~/.profile instead of ~/.bash_profile.

Best of luck!

Comment: @chiragsorathiya, type cd ~ then vim .bashrc

Comment: not working alias gc="git commit" and alias gp="git push"

Comment: @chiragsorathiya did you do echo 'alias gc="git commit"' >> ~/.profile ? You also need to restart the shell. ~ is short for the current users home directory.

Comment: Nothing but `echo 'alias gst="git status"' >> ~/.bashrc` worked for me in Ubuntu18.04.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `aliases` within your shell. 
For **Bash**:

```
echo "alias ga='git add .'" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "alias gc='git commit'" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "alias gp='git push'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Or, for **ZShell**

```
echo "alias ga='git add .'" >> ~/.zshrc
echo "alias gc='git commit'" >> ~/.zshrc
echo "alias gp='git push'" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Once run, simply open your new terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly then below is detailed explanation of how to use alias

[Git Basics - Git Aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

Comment: This will alias the `git` sub-command. So instead of `git push`, you can alias that to be `git p` -- i.e. the alias only applies to the git command, not the parent git cli. Hope that makes sense.