# How to make shortcut for frequently used terminal commands in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have this command :

```
$ anbox session-manager --single-window --window-size=400,650
```

and i need to run it **frequently**, is there any way to avoid **rewriting** it every time I need it ?

Comment: [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a Bash alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967843/how-do-i-create-a-bash-alias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For permanently use

1. run this

   ```
   echo 'alias customcommand="anbox session-manager --single-window --window-size=400,650"' >> /home/$(USER)/.bashrc
   ```
2. open new terminal
3. now you can run `customcommand` and get that response

Answer (score 2):

You can set an alias like this,

```
alias sessmgr = "anbox session-manager --single-window --window-size=400,650"
```

Later, you can directly use `sessmgr`.

Comment: You can't have spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the alias command, and if you want to make the change permanent you can append the alias command in your .bashrc file, so every time you launch a terminal you will have by default the defined alias that you set before in your .bashrc file.
e.g.
`alias <name_of_the_alias>="<command>".`

You can find more info regarding alias [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command))

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this, the most common is probably [using an alias](https://www.tecmint.com/create-alias-in-linux/)

A common alias is using 'll' for 'ls -al', one way you could do that is with the following command:

`alias ll='ls-al'`