# Why ~/.bash_profile doesn't work?

Tags: bash

I'm using Linux Mint. My login shell (`cat /etc/passwd | grep myUserName`) is bash.

After I start my graphical desktop environment and run terminal emulator from it, I could see that `.bash_profile` is not sourced (environment vars that `export` in it is unset). But if I login from text console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) or manually run `bash -l` from terminal emulator, `.bash_profile` works fine.

Am I wrong when I think that `.bash_profile` should source when X starts and all `export`'ed vars should be available in terminal, running from X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably change the default command that a new terminal window runs to be a login shell, which would then source your `.bash_profile`. How to do that is off-topic for Stack Overflow, however.

The other issue is the shells currently started by your terminal emulator inherit their environment not from another login shell, but from your window manager or desktop environment itself. There is probably some configuration file to which you can add environment variables, which will serve the same purpose as `.bash_profile`. Again, this is specific to your WM/DE and off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Use `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`

Here is some explanation:
http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: I have already read this, but I also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902946 where I was told not to `export` variables in `.bashrc` and I found that it is good idea. Environment stuff should be sourced only once.

Comment: This saved my life. Thank you.