# How to reload .bash_profile without changing $PATH?

Tags: bash, unix, path

I'm trying to figure out how I can load changes to my `.bash_profile` without having to logout of my Bash session or exit Terminal, also without affecting my `$PATH`.

In a new session this is my `$PATH`:

```
/Users/MyName/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

And this is the alias I setup to reload my `.bash_profile`:

```
alias reload='source ~/.bash_profile'
```

When I run the `reload` command, my changes to my `.bash_profile` are loaded, but my `$PATH` is lengthened with each time I run the command.

For example:

```
>> reload

>> echo $PATH

/Users/MyName/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/MyName/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

As you can see my `$PATH` is now longer and I think this is because the following is in my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

How can I keep my `$PATH` from being updated with each reload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, trick number one: You reload a script like .bash_profile using

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

The source built-in reads a shell script as if it were coming from standard input, instead of forking a sub shell.

Trick number two: That assignment

```
PATH=/my/new/path:$PATH
```

is just appending what was already in PATH to the new string.  So, it's like doing

```
PATH=/my/new/path:my/old/path/:/my/even/older/path
```

You don't like that behavior, you just reset PATH first.  What I do is like this:

```
PATH=
PATH=/bin:$PATH
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

and so on. Now the path will be exactly what you expect.

**Update**

Here's exactly how my file looks:

```
export PATH=
export PATH=/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:/sbin
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/sbin
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
```

the `exports` aren't really important, as `PATH` is already exported, they're just me being fastidious.

You can also look at this answer for some of the rest of how I set up my shell: [About .bash_profile, .bashrc, and where should alias be written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902946/about-bash-profile-bashrc-and-where-should-alias-be-written-in/902955#902955)

You should look at the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), there's lots of useful stuff there.

Comment: Hi Charlie, I am receiving this error now after adding `PATH=` to my `.bash_profile`:  `env: bash: No such file or directory` and none of my usual commands work. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you need to follow it by setting the components of your path.  That message is telling you that you've got nothing in your path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Charlie. I believe I need to find the file in `.rbenv` that is first adding to my `$PATH` and add the `PATH=` there because I was receiving the error above even when my `$PATH` was subsequently being written to, even though I had the following in my `.bash_profile`: `PATH=`, `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`, `export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"`, and still: `env: bash: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can check before inserting or appending to PATH if the value is not there already:

```
insert_to_path()
{
    if [[ "$PATH" =~ (^|:)"${1}"(:|$) ]]
    then
        return 0
    fi
    export PATH=${1}:$PATH
}

insert_to_path /usr/local/bin
insert_to_path /usr/local/heroku/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of, change your alias so that it stores the existing path and resets it after sourcing the file:

```
alias reload='tmp=$PATH;source ~/.bash_profile;export PATH=$tmp'
```