# creating an alias and then store?

Tags: linux

I want to create an alias like cp, mv, and rm commands then somehow prompts the user for confirmation and store the commands in the bashrc file.
how would I do this? do I just create an alias and then copy them or append them into the ~/.bashrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just copy the exact `alias` command like it was in the console, into the `~/.basrc` file.

Remember that the new alias will take effect after you relaunch the terminal emulator (strictly speaking, the `bash` process).

Edit:

The obligatory [link to the high-rated SO question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902946/about-bash-profile-bashrc-and-where-should-alias-be-written-in).

Comment: tyvm, i have another question, how do i confirm that the aliases are exist in a console? I was able to use an aliases in gui mode, but in console, and it doesn't exist there....

Comment: Issue the `alias` command without arguments to list all the existing aliases.