# create a short cut in mac terminal

Tags: python, django, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to create a short cut for a mac terminal such that when I write 'jj' the following line of code used in terminal will run:

```
python 5_7_16.py
```

My partner can write the program for Linux but he's not able to do it for Mac.  He managed to write the path of the code as follows

```
      FPTH="/Users/kylefoley/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/Proofs/5_7_16.py"
```

When I'm using the pycharm software these are the first two lines of code I use before I can use python 5_7_16.py

```
cd inference2
cd Proofs
```

We already have the python file 'jj' saved in the right location and we can almost get it to work but not quite.

Also, software has three modes: output to excel, output to django, output to mysql.  For reasons that I don't understand my partner thought we needed to write down in our file what type of mode is active.  I don't understand why this is the case because all that information is already stored in the 5_7_16 file.  Just in case it helps, here are the first lines of the python code.

```
excel = True
mysql = False

if not excel and not mysql:
    from inference2.models import Define3, Archives, Input
    from inference2 import views
if mysql:
    import os
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
    print BASE_DIR
    sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "inference_engine2.settings")
    import django
    django.setup()
    from inference2 import views
    from inference2.models import Define3, Archives, Input
```

So here is what he wrote so far, thought again, I don't understand why all this is necessary.  I would think that all you would need would be to just tell the mac terminal what code you want to run:

```
FPTH="/Users/kylefoley/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/Proofs/5_7_16.py"

vmysql=$(sed -i ‘’ -E ’s/^mysql = \(.*\)/\1/g’ $FPTH)
vexcel=$(sed —i ‘’ E ’s/^excel = \(.*\)/\1/g’ $FPTH)
echo $vexcel
echo $vmysql
if [ "$vexcel" == "True" ] ; then
echo "Excel"
elif [ "$vmysql" = "True" ] 
then
echo "Mysql"
else
echo "Django"
fi
if [ "$vexcel" = "True" ] ; then
echo "Excel is set”
python $FPTH
elif [ "$vmysql" = "True" ] 
then
echo "Mysql is set”
python $FPTH
else
echo “Django is set”
cd /dUsers/kylefoley/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2
python manage.py runserver
fi
```

Comment: This is a lot of writing for a very simple thing. Go into `~/.bash_rc` and write `alias jj="python ~/inference2/Proofs/5_7_16.py"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the alias in your `.bash_profile` file. 
For details, check: [About .bash_profile, .bashrc, and where should alias be written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902946/about-bash-profile-bashrc-and-where-should-alias-be-written-in)

Below are the steps to follow:

```
# Step 1: Go To home directory
cd 

# Step 2: Edit ".bash_profile" file OR, create if not exists
vi .bash_profile
# In this file add entry at last as:
# alias jj="python ~/inference2/Proofs/5_7_16.py"
#                  ^ OR whatever is the path to file

# Now, close the file

# Step 3: Refresh bash shell environment
source ~/.bash_profile
```

You are good to do `jj` now.

---

From the bash manpage:

> When  bash is invoked as an
>   interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the
>   `--login` option, it first reads and executes  commands  from  the file
>   `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. 
>   After reading that file, it looks for
>   `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and
>   `~/.profile`, in  that order, and reads
>   and executes commands from the first
>   one that exists and is readable.  The
>   `--noprofile` option may be  used  when  the shell is started to inhibit this
>   behavior.