# I have to run source ~/.bash_profile every time in order to see react-native

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, fish

I added a bunch of aliases to my `.profile` file. None of them work either.

My .bash_profile  has one line: `export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"`

I went as far as creating a .bashrc file and putting `source ~/.bash_profile` in it.

Nothing I have tried is working, other than if I put `source ~/.bash_profile` into my shell every time I open a new one.

I have tried every stack overflow answer I could find and nothing is working.

Anyone out there can help me?

I am on mac, using fish, but same results in bash.

Comment: As a first step of check, could you please check if path `$HOME/.npm-packages/bin` is present or not, may be by doing a `ls -ld $HOME/.npm-packages/bin` and let us know then?

Comment: yes it is present

Comment: Bash and Fish are completely different shells, there's no method that works for both. You should pick one and edit your question not to ask about the other

Comment: See [this previous question about fish startup file(s)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211519/how-to-edit-the-fish-shell-startup-script/211529#211529).

Comment: @GordonDavisson That worked, thanks!  I added export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"  as well as all of my aliases, to this file... ~/.config/fish/config.fish ... and now everything works properly in fish shell. As far as getting my bash shell to work properly, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/902955/3316722)

Answer (score 1):

Fish is not, in general, bash compatible. That means it won't read bash's configuration files and if `source` works on them that's lucky (e.g. `export var=val` will work, `var=val` will not).

You need to either start fish from bash (and have all necessary variables exported), rewrite the necessary configuration for use with fish and add it to config.fish, or use something like https://github.com/edc/bass to read bash's changed environment from fish.