# Alias python3 to python in bash shell

Tags: python, bash, path

The odds of this question being asked are very high, but I cannot find an answer that works for me. I am in a bash shell trying to set my python 3 version (Which I installed with homebrew) to my PATH such that when I run `python` it goes straight into `python3`

```
python --version
Python 2.7.18
python3 --version
Python 3.9.10
which python
/usr/bin/python
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: If `python3 --version` works then it is already in your PATH.

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry. Trying to alias python to be python3

Comment: Sounds like I'm being pedantic, but what exactly does *when I run python* mean?  is that you typing `python` on the terminal?  Is that in a shell script?  Is that what an editor, say `vscode` "sees"?  Are you using a virtualenv?  Depending on what you want to do, `alias python='/usr/bin/python3'` might do the trick  Virtual environments also typically *"find the correct python"* themselves.  I use https://github.com/brettcannon/python-launcher but only since recently.  Before that I had a python alias via `alias py="python3.8"` - not specifying the entire path allows virtualenv to do its thing

Comment: I'd try a `alias python='python3'` in `~/.profile` and see what that gets you.  That leaves macos itself blissfully unaware of any impact to system python.

Comment: See [About .bash_profile, .bashrc, and where should alias be written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/902946/4154375).

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but in case you're not aware of it; is [```pyenv```](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) an option?

Comment: @JLPeyret thanks , fully qualified path works!