# Make $JAVA_HOME easily changable in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, java-home

In Ubuntu, I'd like to switch my JAVA_HOME environment variable back and forth between Java 5 and 6.

I open a terminal and type in the following to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun
```

And in that same terminal window, I type the following to check that the environment variable has been updated:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

And I see **/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun** which is what I'm expecting to see.  In addition, I modify ~/.profile and set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun.

And now for the problem--when I open a new terminal window and I check my JAVA_HOME environment variable by typing in **echo $JAVA_HOME** I see that my JAVA_HOME environment variable has been reverted back to Java 6.  When I reboot my machine (or log out and back in, I suppose) the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to Java 5 (presumably because of the modification I made in my ~/.profile).

Is there a way around this so that I can change my JAVA_HOME environment without having to log out and back in (AND make that environment variable change *stick* in all new terminal windows)?

Comment: What's the correct site and the duplicate answer?

Comment: The `~/.profile` file is only read when you login to Ubuntu, so if you logout/login then JAVA_HOME is set for all terminals and any other applications you run.  If you set JAVA_HOME in `~/.bashrc` it will only be seen by applications run from the terminal.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Put the environment variables into the global `/etc/environment` file:

```
...
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun
...
```

Execute "source /etc/environment" in every shell where you want the variables to be updated:

```
$ source /etc/environment
```

Check that it works:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun
```

Great, no logout needed.

If you want to set JAVA_HOME environment variable in only the terminal, set it in **~/.bashrc** file.

Comment: A restart is still needed for these changes to affect apps launched through the Ubuntu UI (i.e. double clicking an app)

Comment: How is this different than just setting the variable in every friggin' shell?

Comment: @mlissner Yes you need to run a command in each shell, but the value also stays in the `/etc/environment` file permanently. When just setting the variable in every shell, it would be lost again after restart.

Comment: another way to not have to run this manually every time is to modify your .bashrc file to include the command "source /etc/environment"

Comment: this did not work for me until i `export JAVA_HOME;`

Comment: How do I set an envvar to /etc/environment via the command line, like Windows' setx?

Comment: This superuser question suggests a logout/login is needed for this to take effect for all users: http://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting

Comment: @MartinKonicek your example is incorrect. there should be no 'export' on that line. /etc/environment contains key value pairs

Comment: @psychok7 see my last comment

Comment: keep in mind that [`/etc/environment` is special](http://askubuntu.com/a/149668/132098) and does not allow variable substitution, e.g. `JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/jre` won't work.

Comment: @MartinKonicek I don't understand the reason behind it. Configuration files are not executed from what the FHS states.

Answer (score 31):

This will probably solve your problem:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

> **Session-wide environment variables**
>
> In order to set environment variables in a way that affects a particular user's environment, one should not place commands to set their values in particular shell script files in the user's home directory, but use:
>
> ~/.pam_environment - This file is specifically meant for setting a user's environment. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.
>
> **Not recommended:**
>
> ~/.profile - This is probably the best file for placing environment variable assignments in, since it gets executed automatically by the DisplayManager during the startup process desktop session as well as by the login shell when one logs-in from the textual console.

Comment: From the link you provided:

"The below are not recommended but the previous solution (?) provided on this page did not work with the 10.04 desktop release. .pam_environment is not naturally procesed with the distribution. "

Comment: ~/.pam_environment is an awesome way to brick your login if you assume it processes variables. I tried setting PATH to ${PATH}:${HOME}/bin and it failed to evaluate the variables.  Net result: cannot log in :(  Fixed by visiting Ctrl-Alt-1 and running "/bin/rm ~/.pam_environment".  Be exceptionally careful or use a secondary account to test settings here.

Comment: Personally I don't know why they bothered creating the environment file and then had it work in a completely different way than any other mechanism for setting environment variables ever worked before. Simple key value pairs like the environment file uses is plain BS. There is a reason we use variables and links in the environment and it still has merit today. It simplifies administration. Whoever the bozos are who decided the PAM way of doing things in this file was best are imbeciles at best. Variables NEED to be interpreted.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea: I had exactly the same issue. Shocked and worried when I couldn't get past login screen. After some digging around I found that you can use variables but have to use a different syntax. eg. PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin When it's not using a variable, a simple assignment seems to work.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @AlainO'Dea. If there is any error in your script, you will not be able to login. Take care.

Answer (score 13):

Try these steps.

--We are going to edit "etc\profile".
  The environment variables are to be input at the bottom of the file. Since Ubuntu does not 
  give access to root folder, we will have to use a few commands in the terminal

Step1: Start Terminal. Type in command: `gksudo gedit /etc/profile`

Step2: The profile text file will open. Enter the environment variables at the bottom of the page........... **Eg:**  `export JAVA_HOME=/home/alex/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java`

```
export PATH=/home/alex/jdk1.6.0_22/bin:$PATH
```

step3: save and close the file. Check if the environment variables are set by using echo command........ **Eg** `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 9):

You need to put variable definition in the `~/.bashrc` file.

From bash man page:

> When  an  interactive  shell that is
>   not a login shell is started, bash
>   reads and executes commands from 
>   /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc,  if
>   these  files  exist.

Answer (score 5):

Traditionally, if you only want to change the variable in your terminal windows, set it in `.bashrc` file, which is sourced each time a new terminal is opened. `.profile` file is not sourced each time you open a new terminal.

See the difference between .profile and .bashrc in question:
[What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

`.bashrc` should solve your problem. However, it is not the proper solution since you are using Ubuntu. See the relevant Ubuntu help page "[Session-wide environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables)". Thus, no wonder that `.profile` does not work for you. I use Ubuntu 12.04 and xfce. I set up my `.profile` and it is simply not taking effect even if I log out and in. Similar experience [here](http://somethinggroovy.blogspot.de/2012/07/pamenvironment-syntax-in-ubuntu.html). So you may have to use `.pam_environment` file and totally forget about `.profile`, and `.bashrc`. And NOTE that `.pam_environment` is not a script file.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`bash(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), you need a *login shell* to pickup the `~/.profile`, i.e. the `-l` option.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a long cold question, but it comes up every time there is a new or recent major Java release.  Now this would easily apply to 6 and 7 swapping.

I have done this in the past with `update-java-alternatives`:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-java-alternatives.8.html

Answer (score 1):

After making changes to .profile, you need to execute the file, in order for the changes to take effect.

```
root@masternode# . ~/.profile
```

Once this is done, the echo command will work.

Comment: You should use `~/.profile` rather than `./.profile`.