# Netbeans can build and run the java executable; but when executing application outside of Netbeans it doesn't run

Tags: java, ubuntu, executable-jar, unsupported-class-version

I do not know what is causing this to happen. Is it because I am building it wrong in Netbeans. I can build it and run it fine in Netbeans. But when I execute the Jar by clicking on it--nothing happens. So I run it from the terminal by executing this command below:

```
java -jar 'path to jar'
```

Then it gives this stack trace below with error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Security/TabbedWindow : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Security.TabbedWindow. Program will exit.
```

It seems to me that it cannot find the package Security. But I open the Jar file using my favorite archive manager and the package Security seems to be there and all the class files including the Window class file is there. The Jar is signed by the way but I do not think that is what is causing the problem. The strangest thing though was that a couple of days ago I was able to run the jar. But I did upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 LTS. Could it be a problem with Open JDK 7. Any tips, answers, and helpful advice is welcome.

**My Enviroment Variables**

```
SSH_AGENT_PID=6618
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-5PyJ0L/gpg:0:1
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=064a9b6c2b6d727a2883e8c500000097-1335551143.550894-1714410992
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-5PyJ0L
GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module:canberra-gtk-module
USER=danny
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/local
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID=1091386b79c06bc640133555114419341300000065810001
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-5PyJ0L/ssh
SESSION_MANAGER=local/ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/6581,unix/ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/6581
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
PWD=/home/danny
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=6570
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=libappmenu.so
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
HOME=/home/danny
SHLVL=1
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME=danny
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-MrwQLH1prr,guid=547b4d3e0ff3a1907c709b97000013f5
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XAUTHORITY=/home/danny/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

**Another Update**

No I changed the target from JDK 6 and execute the jar and it does nothing and run from the terminal it gives a HeadLess exception. It still runs fine in Netbeans.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:476)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:384)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:174)
    at HomeSecurity.Window.<init>(Window.java:36)
    at HomeSecurity.Window$15.run(Window.java:564)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:647)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:617)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

Comment: What do you get when you run "java -version" and "which java" ?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Those classes were created using a 1.7 SDK without the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#crosscomp-options).  Use the cross-compilation options options to compile code for whatever is the minimum target version of the app.

Comment: I changed the target but now I get a HeadLess exception.

Comment: That is a separate thing, best asked on a separate question.  Please don't try to use one question as a complete 'deploy my app.' saga.

Answer (score 1):

Your class compiled version is different from class running java version. Check JAVA_HOME where your code is running and make sure it is same as your netbeans Java_HOME version.

Comment: I tried to print my environment variables and JAVA_HOME is not showing. I will post my environment vars.

Comment: I am not expert in Ubuntu, but you need to set JAVA_HOME and try.

Comment: Start a terminal. (CTRL-ALT-T) Then at the command prompt enter {export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jvm} http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655641/set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu