# Setting up environment variables in Ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, global-variables, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to setup up my environment variable in my Ubuntu machine. Now I did some research and tryed the method on this question [Make $JAVA_HOME easily changable in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655641/set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu)

Similar question but the thing is I already wrote up the "etc/enviroment" the "etc/profile" and the "etc/bash.bashrc" file to include my variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/glv/information/jdk1.6.0_25/
BASEDIR=/home/glv/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/
```

However the problem is when i run the startup.sh on apache it still says that the BASEDIR enviroment variable is not setup right. I am using the latest Ubuntu not sure if that a problem or not or if i have to go another way around it.

Comment: this question is better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/