# How to set up different environments on Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to set up multiple environments on a Laravel 4 app, and naturally different Databases depending on which environment we are on.

For my local machine, I set up a virtual host for "local.elders.dev"

Unfortunately, for some reason the following code is not working.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('http://local.elders.dev'),
));
```

Maybe I need to run an artisan command or something else. I feel I am close, but not quite there yet !

Thanks to all !

Comment: I don't know what "for some reason it isn't working" menas. Got any sort of PHP error to show off? :)

Comment: Nope, it just doesnt recognise my local environment... I have a database.php file on a 'config/local' folder, but Laravel is still using the production settings for db..

Comment: Type var_dump($_SERVER); die();  before $env, and see what your server name is called - then set it to that

Comment: And also check this link for a possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13860283/1317935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK ! I just solved the issue... The code was actually working ok ! The problem is that I was      using

```
$_SERVER['DB1_HOST'] //for Pagodabox.
```

Of course this was not set on my local environment, which pretty much broke the app...

I fixed by simply doing :

```
isset($_SERVER['DB1_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_HOST'] : '';
```

Thanks to @jeroen and @theshiftexchange :)

Answer (score 4):

Another method is to use the name of the folder the project is in. This works in console and web. I found this to be the only reliable way if different environments are hosted on the same server.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'staging'     => strpos(getcwd(), '/staging')>-1, 
  'acceptance'  => strpos(getcwd(), '/acceptance')>-1, 
  'production'  => strpos(getcwd(), '/production')>-1, 
));
```

A big advantage is that you can move staging to production by simply renaming or copying the project folder without changing files, db records or environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is answered but for others looking for a solution...

My environment detection setting looks like this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

// Development
// any machine name with the term "local" will use the local environment
'local' => array('*local*'),

// Stage
// any machine name with the term "stage" will use the stage environment
'stage' => array('*stage*')

// Production
// production is default, so we don't need to specify any detection
```

));

This is handy because it will work on any project as long as I use "local" for development (like "localhost", "localhost:8000", "my.app.local", etc.). Same goes for "stage". And production is default so anything without "local" or "stage" works for production.

Comment: Murzeb: I'm working in my local machine with WAMP. I have added the above coding in start.php. But the environment value returns production. How can I get local environment? My local URL is http://localhost/laravel-app/public/home. Please advice..

Answer (score 3):

## Handling multiple environments on the same machine with Laravel 4x

What if you wanted to run multiple environments on the same machine with the same name- for example, a **staging** and **production** AND **local** environment?

There is a better solution for handling environments in Laravel 4x- and it can be done by adding a one liner to you vhosts file- or .htaccess:

## Set local environment variable

In vhost or .htaccess add for your local installation, for **staging**, for example add:

```
SetEnv LARAVEL_ENV staging
```

and the same in your **production** .htaccess or vhost:

```
SetEnv LARAVEL_ENV production
```

Then the usual detectEnvironment() function in start.php.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
// Default to local if LARAVEL_ENV is not set
return getenv('LARAVEL_ENV') ?: 'local';
});
```

We didn't forget **local**... and that's the the cool part-- your installation will default to local if neither environment variable is found in vhost or .htaccess, as they would be found in the other installations.

Comment: This is my preferred technique, with one difference: I prefer to default to production. If we default to anything else, then a failure to configure in production could leak internals - like debug dumps, stack traces, etc, - that are likely enabled in pre-production environments.

Comment: Also, remember to prepend the LARAVEL_ENV setting to command-line invocations, either via bash `export` or manually on invocation using something like `LARAVEL_ENV=staging php /path/to/command.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it with `'local.elders.dev'`, I'm not 100% sure but it's probably matching hostnames, not full paths.

Comment: What about `'*.dev'`? If even that isn't matching, there's something wrong with the way you set up the database config file.

Comment: @jeroden You were right. The local environment was being set correctly... I willanswer my own question with how I manage to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4 detects the environments through the machine names specified in the "bootstrap/start.php" file.

For example, in my case the config becomes:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'local' => array('Victor.local', 'Victor-PC'),
));
```

This means that Laravel will use the 'local' environment settings for both machines: 'Victor.local' (a Mac) and 'Victor-PC' (Windows).

In order to know the current machine name, you can use the following PHP code:

`<?php echo gethostname(); ?>`

For each environment you can create a folder in app/config and replace the desired configuration files and properties.

Regards!