# laravel 4 on beanstalk, php artisan how to figure out the environment

Tags: amazon-ec2, laravel-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 3 environments

- development
- staging
- production

When I use **amazon beanstalk** every request goes through a **load balancer** from which point you end up on an **ec2 server** which could be different every time (hence the problem of figuring out the environment, I can't use the machine name as it's different every time).

I found out about environment variables in beanstalk configuration so I pass an environment variable **PARAM_1** from **.ebextensions.myapp.config** that essentially dictates the environment to use with the following trick.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'staging' => $_SERVER['PARAM_1'] == 'staging' ? array(gethostname()) : array('not-staging'),
  'production' => $_SERVER['PARAM_1'] == 'production' ? array(gethostname()) : array('not-production'),
  'development' => array('mylocalname')
));
```

This works fine except for **php artisan commands**! For some reason when running the artisan commands I can not access this environment variable so I'm stuck!
I would like to run **php artisan migrate** but how do I tell it the environment it's in! (based on the environment I have different database configs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the environment like this:

```
php artisan migrate  --env=Development
```

You can also use another SO answer to hard code the artisan enviornment into your code: [Environment driven database settings in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13860283/1317935)