# Java not picking up on environmental variable

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to set an environmental variable in linux.  I followed the instructions here: [Make $JAVA_HOME easily changable in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655641/set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu)

Despite using `source /etc/environment` and using `echo MY_VAR` to verify that linux detects the variable, my java app will not pick up on it.  The variable continues to return `null`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.print(System.getenv("MY_VAR"));
```

I'm executing my java application via `sudo java -jar /path/to/my.jar`

**Update:** My mistake, I hadn't included the correct command.  I'm actually sudoing.

Comment: Are u able to get other variables such as JAVA_HOME?

Comment: try setting JAVA_HOME it in .bashrc in /home

Comment: Try printing out System.getenv(). This will return a map. Display that to see which all variables u are able to see. Then check if the key is same as the one that you specified while setting the variable

Comment: Please copy your shell session into the question, so that we can see what exactly you're doing.

Comment: Are you sure that the variables are the same?  Your question suggests that one is `MY_VAR` and the other is `MY_ENVIRONMENT`.

Comment: @devnull - Yes sorry, that was a mistake in my example, but the actual vars are the same.

Comment: @Pratik - Done, and my environment variable doesn't show up there at all

Comment: @Webnet if you run the Java program as a different user then have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo how to pass the environment variable

Comment: Did you try the -E flag to sudo?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to export the variable

```
export MY_VAR=stackoverflow
java -jar /path/to/my.jar
```

then you can print the value with

```
System.out.print(System.getenv("MY_VAR"));
```

**edit**: short example script (amend the path if necessary)

```
#!/bin/sh

MY_VAR="foobaz not exported"
echo "MY_VAR: ${MY_VAR}"
java -jar my.jar

export MY_VAR="foobaz exported"
echo "MY_VAR: ${MY_VAR}"
java -jar my.jar
```

Comment: Doing this, it is still null... :-\

Comment: @Webnet have a look on the added short example. If it's still not working for you, you should show the steps you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

from the linked answer ..

> Execute "source /etc/environment" in every shell where you want the variables to be updated:

When you call `java -jar /path/to/my.jar` I think you will be starting a new shell, meaning that the contents of ./etc/environment wont be available to the shell your java code is running in.

try

```
export MY_ENVIRONMENT="HELLO"
java -jar /path/to/my.jar
```

Does that look any better?

And if you are sudo -ing your command ...

```
sudo -c export MY_ENVIRONMENT="HELLO";java -jar /path/to/my.jar
```

or something along those lines

Comment: It's still `null` in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

The **issue is that sudo runs with it's own set of environment variables**. You can either add the variable to the root environment (sometimes finicky), or tell sudo to maintain the current environment's variables explicitly.

Here's how you would do the latter:

1. Open up your bash profile
   `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2. Add the environment variable to the file `export MY_VAR=80`
3. Open up the sudoers config file `sudo visudo`
4. Add the following line to the file exactly as so `Defaults        env_keep +="MY_VAR"`

Now when you run `sudo java -jar /path/to/my.jar` it should work as desired, with MY_VAR set to 80.