# No default JAVA_HOME on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat7

I'm trying to install tomcat7 using Ansible. After installation, when restarting service, I'm getting errors because there is no java_home set :

```
no JDK or JRE found - please set JAVA_HOME
```

I know I can set the java_home value in /etc/default/tomcat7, but what I'm looking for, is why JAVA_HOME is not set by default to the only installed Java and we have to do it manually before starting any Java application/server :

```
update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java Nothing to configure.
```

I'm using trusty 14.04 and openjdk8

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655641/make-java-home-easily-changable-in-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: ubuntu java installation packages don't set JAVA_HOME by default. What kind of answer to this question do you expect to get?

Answer (score 1):

Your `JAVA_HOME` would appear to be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`, to set it persistently as `root` create `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` with

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

and make it executable,

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
```

You need to logout and log back in for that to take effect, or you can execute

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

And it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

go to home directory and press `ctrl+h` and show hidden files then create `.bash_aliases` file into home folder.

and write two line into `.bash_aliases` file. `/home/hadoop/install/jdk1.8.0_92` by your current jdk path. then restart terminal and check `java -version`, you get the version details.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/hadoop/install/jdk1.8.0_92
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```