# How can I automatically load alias on startup?

Tags: linux

I am trying to add the `alias ll = "ls -l"`, and I am wondering how can I load it every time I login to linux.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add it to your `~/.bashrc` file in your home directory.

For more information on `.bashrc` and the likes, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bashprofile-and-environment).

Comment: This gave me the answeR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment/415444#415444

Answer (score 12):

You can add your aliases to `~/.bashrc` as explained by cschol but, if you prefer a tidier solution, then you can include all of your additions in one or more files.

Many distributions already do it by default. Just add the following code to your `.bashrc` file:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

And then just add your aliases to `~/.bash_aliases`

Answer (score 6):

In addition to adding it to ~/.bashrc (which only affects the current user), it can be added to /etc/profile, which will affect all users upon login.