# Adding a directory to PATH in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, path

I am a new user of Linux, just switched from Windows. I installed ActiveTcl-8.5 in `/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/`, now I want to add its `bin` directory to the UNIX path.

I have read a number of articles from the net and got confused about which file to modify. My `/home/tofayel` directory contains `.bashrc`, `.bash_logout`, `.bash_history`, and `.profile`; but not `.bash_login` and `.bash_profile`.

Where do I add the extra lines to add `/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin` to PATH?

Comment: You probably want to put it in .bashrc. Have a look at this answer for an explanation about the different files - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment

Answer (score 75):

The file `.bashrc` is read when you start an interactive shell. This is the file that you should update. E.g:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin
```

Restart the shell for the changes to take effect or source it, i.e.:

```
source .bashrc
```

Comment: Surely your shell will already have performed the `export`; no need to do it again.

Comment: *[How can I correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047)* says *"You should not define environment variables in ~/.bashrc"*

Answer (score 11):

Actually I would advocate `.profile` if you need it to work from scripts, and in particular, scripts run by /bin/sh instead of Bash. If this is just for your own private interactive use, `.bashrc` is fine, though.

Comment: @Fredrik Pihi , @reader_1000 : I opened the `.profile` file and found that it imports `.bashrc` file. 
Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: That's not a sane arrangement. Maybe post a separate question, maybe on https://superuser.com/ as this is definitely moving away from programming-related.

Answer (score 9):

you can set it in .bashrc

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin;export PATH;
```

Comment: To clarify what reader_1000 said: open .bashrc add to the end of this file these 2 lines: (PATH=$PATH:/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin; export PATH;) then run command "source .bashrc" to load your new configuration.

Comment: *[How can I correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047)* says *"You should not define environment variables in ~/.bashrc"*