# Cant run sloth annotation tool

Tags: python, annotations, installation, setuptools

Im trying to use annotation tool [Sloth](http://sloth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-sloth).
how do i get the program to run?

```
JMAIR-3:sloth user$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
JMAIR-3:sloth user$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
JMAIR-3:sloth user$ brew install PyQt
Warning: pyqt-4.11.4 already installed
JMAIR-3:sloth user$ ls
COPYING     LICENSE     README.md   build       doc     examples    scripts     setup.py    sloth       tests
JMAIR-3:sloth user$ sloth
-bash: sloth: command not found
JMAIR-3:sloth user$ sudo python setup.py install 
Password:
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sloth to 755
running install_data
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sloth-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sloth-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
JMAIR-3:sloth user$ sloth
-bash: sloth: command not found
JMAIR-3:sloth user$ sloth examples/example1_labels.json
-bash: sloth: command not found


 python sloth
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: can't find 'main' module in 'sloth'
```

Comment: I'm trying to run it on Windows, having a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sloth is an executable Python script . So, to run it you can call it from terminal:

```
PATH_PREFIX_TO_YOUR_PYTHON/Python27/Lib/site-packages/sloth/bin/sloth
```

You might [add sloth script directory to your PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360889/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-ubuntu) , by editing yout `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:PUT_PATH_TO_SLOTH_HERE
```

And then run `source .bashrc` in order for changes to take effect. After that, typing `sloth` in a terminal window should open the GUI.

In Windows, I managed to run it using [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) (Git installation for Windows provides a Bash emulator by default) . In a Git Bash terminal Window, use the following (you may need to chage if your Python installation directory is different):

```
/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/sloth/bin/sloth
```

Comment: this sounds standard, but keep getting sloth command not found, even after exporting the path as you've described and sourcing it (which i do for most other packages with success). so maybe ive got a non standard install path that sloth doesnt expect or something..

Answer (score 3):

The following works on Windows, with an Anaconda python 3.5 build (and installs all the dependencies):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/cvhciKIT/sloth.git
conda install -c anaconda pyqt=4.11.4
conda install scikit-image
```

Answer (score 0):

**complete installation "sloth" under Windows:**

1. `conda create -n slo_py35 python=3.5`
2. `activate slo_py35
   git config --global http.proxy http://proxy.xxx.de:port #only if proxy available
   pip install git+https://github.com/cvhciKIT/sloth.git`
3. `conda install -c anaconda pyqt=4.11.4
   conda install scikit-image #or if it does not work, take: pip install scikit-image`
4. `conda env list #shows the path to the installation
   for example: D:\...\anaconda3\envs\slo_py35\`
5. run sloth:
   `D:\...\anaconda3\envs\slo_py35\sloth\bin> python sloth`
6. run sloth with the included example:
   `D:\...\anaconda3\envs\slo_py35\sloth\bin> python sloth D:\xxx\examples\example1_labels.json`

possible problems:
`FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'D:\...\anaconda3\envs\slo_py35\lib\site-packages\sloth\gui\labeltool.ui'`

solutions: the ui-file exists and is just in the wrong place
`D:\...\anaconda3\envs\slo_py35\sloth\gui\labeltool.ui`
The ui-file only needs to be copied to the correct path, see error message, then it runs.