# Implementing Atom with Python Language Server

Tags: python, ide, atom-editor, python-language-server

I am new here. I am trying to setup the python IDE on Atom following the instruction offered by Atom.io.

https://atom.io/packages/ide-python

There is an instruction:

"Depending on your Python setup pyls may be installed in a non default folder. In this case either add the directory to your PATH or edit the "Python Language Server Path" setting of ide-python to point to the pyls executable."

I stucked here.
What does it mean? How to add this to the PATH?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was failing because pyls didn't work with Python 2.7
Error

```
error in python-language-server setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected version spec in configparser; python_version<"3.0" at ; python_version<"3.0"
```

So I installed Python 3.6 and followed you note forcing 3.6

```
python3.6 -m pip install python-language-server[all]
```

That did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: How did you figure this out? What command(s) did you type to learn what was not working?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution:

1. Run from terminal to install pyls:

> pip install 'python-language-server[all]'

2. Print out details of WHERE the python language server was installed:

> pip show python-language-server

Which gave me the path:

> Location: /home/bad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I browsed to that path and found the 'pyls' folder. Then I went into atom and edited the configuration to point at '/home/bad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyls'. Specifically, if I go into EDIT>CONFIG in the Atom menu I have this:

> "*":
>     "atom-ide-ui":
>       use: {}
>     core:
>       telemetryConsent: "no"
>     "exception-reporting":
>       userId: "30865088-5ba0-4a4b-bfd9-04fa28903321"
>     "ide-python":
>       pylsPath: "/home/bad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyls"

I suppose you could also add the pyls folder to path, once you find the path, following these instructions:
[Adding a directory to PATH in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360889/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-ubuntu)