# Why did RVM/Bundler integration break RVM from loading with Terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

**NOTE: I have fixed/hacked this problem in my environment (details below), but I would really like to understand what happened & provide a resource if this happens to others. Hopefully this is an OK use of Stack. :)**

I'm going through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial (2nd Edition), and I hit my first major snag today.

In chapter 3, [section 3.6.1 "Eliminating Bundle Exec"](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:eliminating_bundle_exec), I executed these commands to get Ruby Version Manager (RVM) to 'adjust' my path for all projects such that I can stop typing *bundle exec* so often:

```
$ rvm get head && rvm reload
$ chmod +x $rvm_path/hooks/after_cd_bundler
$ cd /path/to/project
$ bundle install --binstubs=./bundler_stubs
```

..and voila! I can no longer run *bundle*, *rvm*, or many other common functions (I'm still new to Rails, so I don't know what relationship or origins these commands share). I did a full reboot because I come from Windows, and that's just what you do when shit gets funky, but the issue persisted! BLLARG!

**The error is the same for bundle, rvm, etc:**

> -bash: rvm: command not found

(NOTE: Also around this time, I modified *xcode-select -switch* from /Developer to some other longer, crazier path - see [this link for details](https://github.com/thibaudgg/rb-fsevent/issues/26) if you think this might play a role)

I did some digging, and found that this may have something to do with my $PATH, so here is my *env $PATH*, if it matters:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

The PATH seemed wrong - there was supposed to be some RVM stuff in there, or some bundler stuff in there - that was the point of the change! - so I did some more digging, and discovered that my file system was still intact and looking good (RVM still installed, Gemfile still correct, etc), and yet in my Terminal session the version of Ruby was old (v1.8.7), and Rails wasn't even installed, so it started to seem more like session- or RVM-specific problem.

Did some more digging and found that if I MANUALLY ran the following commands (from **~/.bash_login**) in Terminal, everything worked:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

YES!

When I closed & re-opened Terminal, the problem returned, but when I re-executed the command above the problem was fixed again. So clearly this is just a matter of something not getting loaded correctly in Terminal, right?

I moved the command above in to **~/.bash_profile** (which was previously empty other than prompt stylings), and the problem is totally fixed for me. I can close & reopen Terminal, and I'm off to the races.

**BUT WHAT HAPPENED?!** Why was that command in **~/.bash_login** instead of **~/.bash_profile**? I'd love to understand what's going on so that I get less n00bly & so that others can avoid the 2-hour Google searching adventure that I just had. :)

Thanks!

Environment:

- Mac OS X 10.7.4 (Lion)
- Terminal (built-in)
- Sublime Text 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick one of the files and merge it to the second.

RVM checks both files, it's enough that one contains loading RVM and it will work.

To get rid of `bundle exec` you can use my gem **rubygems-bundler**, it will be integrated to bundler 1.3 so no more additional tools/scripts/tricks will be required then.

Comment: thanks mpapis - but my question is more about why the following command broke my environment (not how to fix it): $ rvm get head && rvm reload
$ chmod +x $rvm_path/hooks/after_cd_bundler
$ cd /path/to/project
$ bundle install --binstubs=./bundler_stubs

Comment: check my first sentence, you need to merge your login files

Comment: why did it work before I ran the commands in my previous comment? why did those changes cause my environment to fail? shouldn't RVM tread my ~/.bash_profile and other related files the same in both cases? i realize this question is purely academic - but that's the point for me right now. :)

Comment: check https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login and https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ ... rvm1 will continue changing your *rc files, in rvm2 you will be able to choose from set of components, where only one will require modifying *rc files

Comment: ok - although i still don't fully understand the reason behind this problem, it is enough to know that it will be a non-issue sooner than later - this accomplishes my goal/reason for posting. thanks mpapis!

Answer (score 0):

Well, login scripts will run at different times. You can see some details in this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment). But according to [this](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php), `~/.bash_login` is an alias for `~./bash_profile`. So I'm not sure why one runs for you while the other doesn't.

However, on my system (Mac OS X 10.6) I don't have a `~/.bash_login` file. And I have both rvm and bundler.

Possibly related - I have Homebrew installed and it suggests my path to have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`. This is so Homebrew installed items and items I install myself will have priority over system installed ones.

Comment: thanks dty - but my question is more about why the following command broke my environment (not how to fix it): $ rvm get head && rvm reload $ chmod +x $rvm_path/hooks/after_cd_bundler $ cd /path/to/project $ bundle install --binstubs=./bundler_stubs